# How to capitalize the first letter of text in a TextView in an Android Application

Tags: android, xml

I'm not referring to textInput, either. I mean that once you have static text in a TextView (populated from a Database call to user inputted data (that may not be Capitalized)), how can I make sure they are capitalized?

Thanks!

Comment: For future visitors... In Kotlin just use "abcd".capitalize())

Comment: `capitalize`is deprecated, I've added why and workaround as an answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67482851/80428

Answer (score 221, accepted):

I should be able to accomplish this through standard java string manipulation, nothing Android or TextView specific.

Something like:

```
String upperString = myString.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + myString.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Although there are probably a million ways to accomplish this.  See [String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) documentation.

**EDITED**
I added the `.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Just wanted to note that this is a good solution for English, but not localization friendly.

Answer (score 84):

Following does not apply to TextView, but works with EditText; even then, it applies to the text entered from the keyboard, not the text loaded with setText(). To be more specific, it turns the Caps on in the keyboard, and the user can override this at her will.

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

or

```
TV.sname.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

---

This will CAP the first letter.

or

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4' //in build.gradle module(app)

tv.setText(StringUtils.capitalize(myString.toLowerCase().trim()));
```

Comment: This does not apply to TextView, but only to EditText; even then, it applies to text entered from keyboard, not the text loaded with setText(). To be more specific, it turns the Caps on in the keyboard, and the user can override this at her will.

Answer (score 37):

for Kotlin, just call

```
textview.text = string.capitalize()
```

Comment: I would have thought it would capitalize each word but it is indeed working for the first word only.

Comment: If you are using this in the multilingual app, passing locale makes it better.

Comment: Capitalize was deprecated as of 1.5, added my answer to alternative here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67482851/80428

Answer (score 34):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name);
sb.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(0)));  
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 10):

You can add [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) 
in Gradle like `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'`

And use `WordUtils.capitalizeFully(name)`

Comment: info: lang3 WordUtils is deprecated, you should use "org.apache.commons.text.WordUtils" instead: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 4):

For future visitors, you can also (best IMHO) import `WordUtil` from `Apache` and add a lot of useful methods to you app, like `capitalize` as shown here:

[How to capitalize the first character of each word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java)

Answer (score 4):

For me none of working:

**Function:**

```
private String getCapsSentences(String tagName) {
    String[] splits = tagName.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
        String eachWord = splits[i];
        if (i > 0 && eachWord.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        String cap = eachWord.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() 
                + eachWord.substring(1);
        sb.append(cap);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**Result:**

**I/P** `brain` **O/P** Brain

**I/P** `Brain and Health` **O/P** `Brain And Health`

**I/P** `brain And health` to **O/P** `Brain And Health`

**I/P** `brain's Health` to **O/P** `Brain's Health`

**I/P** `brain's Health and leg` to **O/P** `Brain's Health And Leg`

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is good, but if you are using it to get values from a textView in android, it would be good to check if the string is empty. If the string is empty it would throw an exception.

```
private String capitizeString(String name){
    String captilizedString="";
    if(!name.trim().equals("")){
       captilizedString = name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
    }
    return captilizedString;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For Kotlin, if you want to be sure that the format is "Aaaaaaaaa" you can use :

```
myString.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).capitalize()
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that Kotlin's `.capitalize()` [is deprecated as of 1.5](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/capitalize.html) as it isn't locale friendly. The suggestion is to use `.replaceFirstChar()`

Android Studio warns me

> Implicitly using the default locale is a common source of bugs: Use capitalize(Locale) instead. For strings meant to be internal use Locale.ROOT, otherwise Locale.getDefault().

Thanks to the built in autofix, I made this extension function

```kotlin
fun String.titlecase(): String =
    this.replaceFirstChar { // it: Char
        if (it.isLowerCase())
            it.titlecase(Locale.getDefault())
        else
            it.toString()
    }
```

Comment: Kotlin [release docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew15.html#stable-locale-agnostic-api-for-upper-lowercasing-text) say use `String.replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() }` as alternative. it uses `Locale.ROOT`

Answer (score 4):

Add Kotlin Extension

```kotlin
fun String.firstCap() = this.lowercase().replaceFirstChar { 
    it.uppercase()
}
```

Usecase

```kotlin
"lowercase letter".firstCap() //gives "Lowercase letter"
```

Comment: This will not work if you provide text with First capital or all capital. Ex. TEST & Test. So you need to convert it to lowerCase first. Then this solution will work.

Comment: thanks for flagging it, updated the answer to handle this case

Answer (score 1):

Please create a custom TextView and use it :

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CapitalizedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        if (text.length() > 0) {
            text = String.valueOf(text.charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + text.subSequence(1, text.length());
        }
        super.setText(text, type);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I make this CustomTextView to be appeared in Design of Activity/Fragments as drag and drop UI element?

Answer (score 1):

Here I have written a detailed article on the topic, as we have several options, [Capitalize First Letter of String in Android](https://handyopinion.com/capitalize-first-letter-of-string-in-android-kotlin-java/)

**Method to Capitalize First Letter of String in Java**

```
public static String capitalizeString(String str) {
        String retStr = str;
        try { // We can face index out of bound exception if the string is null
            retStr = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
        }catch (Exception e){}
        return retStr;
}
```

**Method to Capitalize First Letter of String in Kotlin**

```
fun capitalizeString(str: String): String {
        var retStr = str
        try { // We can face index out of bound exception if the string is null
            retStr = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
        return retStr
}
```

**Using XML Attribute**

Or you can set this attribute in TextView or EditText in XML

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using Jetpack Compose, you should use Compose's `String.capitalize(locale: Locale)`, instead of Kotlin's, as follows:

```
import androidx.compose.ui.text.capitalize
import androidx.compose.ui.text.intl.Locale
    
Text("my text".capitalize(Locale.current)) // capitalizes first letter
Text("my text".toUpperCase(Locale.current)) // all caps
```

Answer (score 1):

by using below property

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textCapWords"
```

Comment: Only when it's an EditText. Not on normal textview. It'll give you a warning in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

```
 val text = "FRIDAY"
 val result = text.lowercase().replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() }
 println(result) //output: Friday
```

***[Note: If you did not add lowercase() before converting it, it will not work properly when already your first letter is uppercase.]***

Answer (score 0):

These lines of code helped me

```
String[] message_list=message.split(" ");
    String full_message="";

    for (int i=0; i<message_list.length; i++)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(message_list[i]);
        sb.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(0)));
        full_message=full_message+" "+sb;
    }

    textview_message.setText(full_message);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android XML this can be done with data-binding.

Once enabled in the `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
}
```

One can use it to generate data-bindings from XML, which do permit simple code statements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <import type="java.util.Locale"/>
    </data>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/role"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text='@{ user.role != null ? user.role.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()) + user.role.substring(1) : "n/a" }'
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</layout>
```

Obviously, one could as well import Kotlin or JetPack Compose classes ...

Answer (score 0):

```
//Capitalize the first letter of the words
public String Capitalize(String str) {
    String[] arr = str.split(" "); //convert String to StringArray
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String w : arr) {
        if (w.length() > 1) {
            stringBuilder.append(w.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(Locale.US) + w.substring(1).toLowerCase(Locale.US) + " ");
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
fun TextView.capitalizeWords() {
    text = text.split(" ").joinToString(" ") { it.replaceFirstChar { char -> char.uppercaseChar() } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update 2023 June,
Use this Extension

```
fun String.toTitleCase() = replaceFirstChar { text -> if (text.isLowerCase()) text.titlecase(
Locale.getDefault()) else text.toString() }
```

Answer (score -1):

With Kotlin:

```
textview.text = string.replaceFirstChar(Char::uppercase)
```