# Decapitalizing text in Android view

Tags: android, android-view, textview

I want to insert a text into an Android view, like a button.
The problem is that I want the capitalize some specific characters in my text, but Android capitalize all the text I in the text field. For example, I labeled a button with the text "ExaMple" in which I capitalize the characters "e" and "m", then I saw "EXAMPLE" instead. Anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: In new API 22 text is default capital.Can you tell which style and API you are using?

Comment: Is there any way to decapitalize text?

Comment: yes. you can change it from style.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capitalize a the first letter of text in a TextView in an Android Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419521/how-to-capitalize-a-the-first-letter-of-text-in-a-textview-in-an-android-applica)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add: `android:textAllCaps="false"` to the style of the button

so change:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/TestButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ExaMple" />
```

to:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/TestButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:text="ExaMple" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To decapitalize all text in Project use style.xml.

```
-->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/CustomTheme.ButtonTextAppearance</item>

        <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>-->
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.





        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme.ButtonTextAppearance" parent="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
```

This is my project style.xml. you need to use only AppTheme part into your style.