# Capitalize the first letter in Android TextView using XML

Tags: android

I read plenty questions about that, for example:

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419521/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-text-in-a-textview-in-an-android-applicati)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177726/how-to-change-first-letter-of-each-word-to-uppercase-in-textview-xml/35177919)
- [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434588/is-there-a-way-to-style-a-textview-to-uppercase-all-of-its-letters)

Still, I didn't find a way to just capitalize the first letter of TextView text using XML. So far it looks like it's impossible but it is hardly believable to me.

So, how to capitalize the first letter of Android TextView text using XML?

Comment: You have to do it programmatically.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen That's not a duplicate since Op stated clearly that he has already look at this question, but he want to do it using XML and not Java

Comment: @GavinWright that's what I was afraid of. Thanks.

Comment: @vincrichaud True, [How to change First letter of each word to Uppercase in Textview xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177726/how-to-change-first-letter-of-each-word-to-uppercase-in-textview-xml/35177919) would be closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can't achieve that behaviour using only `XML` files, but if you extend the `TextView` class to a custom one that capitalises the first letter, then you should be able to use only `XML` from this point on.

```
public class CapitalizeTextView extends TextView {
    // Create here constructors matching super

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(text);
        builder.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(builder.charAt(0)));
        super.setText(builder.toString(), type);
    }
}
```

From this point on, you only have to use `CapitalizeTextView` instead of `TextView` and the first letter will be capitalised. It works from `XML` or `Java/Kotlin`.

```
<mobile.com.capitalize.CapitalizeTextView
    ......
    android:text="not capital letter" />


textView.setText("not capital letter");
```

Comment: Hey, this is actually cool. I won't use it in my code because it is a pretty heavy thing for something as small as capitalization but in general, it is good!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting the `capitalize` attribute.

From [the doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:capitalize)

> 0 : Don't capitalize
>
> 1 : Capitalize first letter of sentences
>
> 2 : Capitalize first letter of words
>
> 3 : Capitalize everything

Comment: This does not work I'm afraid. It works only with EditText and it only helps the user in typing. What is more, it is deprecated :/