# Make the next character of a space as capital

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capitalize First Char of Each Word in a String Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java)

I have a string `"abc def ghi"` , I want to make it as `"Abc Def Ghi"`.Similarly I also have a string like `"abc def"` and I want to make it `"Abc Def"`.**In java how is it possible?**

Comment: Can you clarify if you are interested only in ascii characters? If not then answer will be not that trivial as it sounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println(
  org.apache.commons.lang.WordUtils.capitalize(
    "yellow fox jumped over brown foot"
  )
);
```

output:

```
Yellow Fox Jumped Over Brown Foot
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the [capitalize](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29) method from the WordUtils class of ACL.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most effective, but may give you a starting point:

```
public String capitalize(String original) {
        String[] parts = original.split(" ");

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

        for (String part : parts) {
            String firstChar = part.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
            result.append(firstChar + part.substring(1));
            result.append(" ");
        }

        String capitalized = result.toString();

        return capitalized.substring(0, capitalized.length()-1);
}
```

Comment: However the answer from codaddict is much better :)