# How to combine InputStreamReader with StringBuffer?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

public class MyName
{
    public static void main (String [] xxx) throws IOException
    {
        String a;

        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        System.out.print("Input A Name : ");
                    a = read.readLine();
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println("Your Name : " +a);
        System.out.println("Name Capacity: " +a.capacity());
        System.out.println("Length Of A Name : "+a.length());

        /*After the first word of the name (if the name is more than one word) 
                  then the first letter of each word must in uppercase*/
        System.out.println((a)+" change to = ".....); //i have no idea what code to wite
    }
}
```

Input: daniel day lewis

Expected output :

daniel day lewis = ... -> capacity of input string

daniel day lewis = ... -> length of input string

"daniel day lewis" changed to "daniel Day Lewis"

---

Comment: What is exactly your question? How to capitalize words un a String? Reading subsequent lines from the message?

Comment: @fortysant, your title apparently does not match the question that is somewhat hidden in the code. Please edit it again, change title and add a few words to describe what you really need. An example Strings for input and expected output would be helpful too!

Comment: You want to capitalise a set of words in a string? eg. "daniel day lewis" -> "Daniel Day Lewis"

Comment: @Andreas : my title is "how to combine InputStreamReader with StringBuffer"....



@Dunes : yes..

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [Capitalize First Char of Each Word in a String Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java)

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Apache Commons / Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang), you can do this:

```
String capitalized = WordUtils.capitalize(orig);
```

And if you want to enforce Title Case (e.g. no other Upper Case letters except the initials), you can do this (thanks [@manoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454686/manoj)):

```
String capitalized = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(orig);
// almost equivalent to WordUtils.capitalize(orig.toLowerCase());
```

**Reference:**

- [`WordUtils.capitalize(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`WordUtils.capitalizeFully(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I think CapitalizeFully() is better to avoid any typos and accidental upper case in the middle of the words.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel (which is always a good move), you should use Sean Patrick Floyd's suggestion for Apache Commons.

---

If you want to use just core Java, you might be interested in [java.text.BreakIterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) for making your own `toTitleCase` function. `BreakIterator.getWordInstance()` can be used to substring specific words:

For example, "Zach L" would be interpreted by `BreakIterator` as ["Zach", " ", "L"] (brackets used just for emphasis).

In our custom `toTitleCase` function, which takes a String called `string` as a parameter, we could loop over each 'word' using a BreakIterator, set up something like this:

```
BreakIterator words = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();
string = string.toLowerCase();
words.setText(string);
int start = words.first();
for (int end = words.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; 
     start = end, end = words.next())
{
```

We set our parameter, string, to lower case just for ease later. It shouldn't be too hard from here to get the subwords by substringing between `start` and `end`, titlecase the words, and concatenate or append them to the String we return. (As a little extra hint, you mind find it helpful to use [Character.toUpper](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29) on the character at `start`).

Once again, though, it's probably **much** better to use Sean Patrick Floyd's suggestion. This is just offered as an alternative.

For future reference, it's better to put your problem in the question text, rather than just as comments in your code. Otherwise, a lot of our first reactions might be that you aren't asking a real question.

Comment: thank u for the code and thanks for the advice... i'm a newbie in java code...and i'm from indonesia so i'm sorry if my english not well....

Comment: +1 for the BreakIterator solution. Haven't used this class yet!

Comment: @fortysant: We all have to start as newbies (I'm still pretty much a newbie myself) at some point. Good luck with Java!

Answer (score 1):

What is your question? I did not understand!

One idea of you question title is this:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
String s;
while(s=br.readLine() != null) {
    sb.append(s);
}
```

But I do not understand you problems.
Greetings.