# Changing list of NAMES TYPED IN CAPITALS to Names Typed In Capitals with Java

Tags: java, string, capitalization

Lets say I have file with sever hundred lines of text all in capital letters.
How should I go about changing the words on each line to lower case with only the first letter staying as capital?

```
 TEXT ON FIST LINE
 TEXT ON SECOND LINE
 TEXT ON THIRD LINE
```

to

```
 Text On Fist Line
 Text On Second Line
 Text On Third Line
```

I was thinking something like this

```
 s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase()
```

But using StringBuilder would be probably smarter and there is probably even something better than StringBuilder.

Comment: if its all in upper case you wouldnt have to toUpperCase() the first Part

Comment: Isn't this essentially a duplicate of [Capitalize First Char of Each Word in a String Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using apace commons, you can use [`WordUtils.capitalize()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29) or [`WordUtils.capitalizeFully()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

Four options (actually 5, but one is a variation of another):

1. Use a library that already handles
   sentence type capitalization
2. Split the sentence and then upper case the first letter of each word
3. Regex for space + letter and replace the end of the pattern with a capitalized version
4. Run through the string and capitalize after a space is reached

The #5, a variation of #4, is still running through the string, but as binary. This is not difficult, but it changes based on whether this is ASCII or Unicode and may change due to character set.

If you do this with a custom routine, set it up as a reusable class, as I can almost guarantee you will use this again.

Comment: As an aside, I agree with Bala on the "buy versus build" decision.