# Capitalizing an entire word in Struts2 / OGNL

Tags: struts2, ognl

I just can't see it.  I want to do the equivalent of the following:

```
listValue="%{capitalize(remoteUserName)}"
```

inside an `s:select` tag.

According to the struts documentation http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.2/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/inject/util/Strings.html there exists a capitalize function.  I have tried both the above and Strings.capitalize to try to capitalize remoteUserName.

Wandering through what is left of OGNL documentation at http://incubator.apache.org/ognl/, I don't see a way immediately to capitalize in this way.

So what then is the syntax to capitalize when using struts 2 tags?

**EDIT:**

I realize that the idea I put forth was to capitalize just the first letter of the word.  Really, I would like each character in the word capitalized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of using com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.Strings (has been tested)

```
<s:property value="@com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.Strings@capitalize(myString)"/>
```

This requires that static method invocation be enabled, to do that simply add,

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/> 
</struts>
```

into struts.xml

**Edit**: Just so others know (you probably already do) you can use any of the methods of java.lang.String ie: myString.toUpperCase() is a valid expression and you could use a regular expression and the java.lang.String methods *replaceFirst* or *replaceAll* to achieve the desired result.

If com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.Strings *capitalize* method does not meet your needs this question covers other methods which might be useful: [How to capitalize the first character of each word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java)

Comment: `<s:property value="@com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.Strings@capitalize(myString)"/>` is exactly the type of solution I was looking for.  I already had allowStaticMethodAccess inside of my struts.xml file.  However, I misstated what I was looking for.  Your fix does what is advertised, however I really need the entire word capitalized.  That is my mistake in communication.

Comment: That is much easier, you don't need staticMethodAccess, just write myString.toUppercase()

Comment: Change your comment to myString.toUpperCase() and I can accept your solution :)  Thanks.