# parse string to remove spaces java

Tags: java, parsing

I need some help parsing a string that is input to one that is later cleaned and output.

e.g.

```
String str = " tHis  strIng is  rEalLy mEssy  "
```

and what I need to do is have it parsed from that to look like this:

```
"ThisStringIsReallyMessy"
```

so I basically need to clean it up then set only the first letter of every word to capitals, without having it break in case someone uses numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String[] tokens = " tHis  strIng is  rEalLy mEssy  ".split(" ");
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for(String token : tokens) {
    if(!token.isEmpty()) {
        result.append(token.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()).append(token.substring(1).toLowerCase());
     }
}
System.out.println(result.toString()); // ThisStringIsReallyMessy
```

Answer (score 5):

Apache Commons to the rescue (again). As always, it's worth checking out the Commons libraries not just for this particular issue, but for a lot of functionality.

You can use Apache Commons [WordUtils.capitalize()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29) to capitalise each word within the string. Then a `replaceAll(" ", "")` will bin your whitespace.

```
String result = WordUtils.capitalize(str).replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Note (other) Brian's comments below re. the choices behind `replace()` vs `replaceAll()`.

Comment: Note that `replaceAll` takes a regex. Use `replace` for non-regex replacement since it's faster and does the same thing. Also on that note, `replaceAll("\\s+", "")` will also replace tabs and other whitespace besides the space character.

Comment: @Brian - I've amended my answer to refer to your comment above. Thx

Answer (score 4):

```
   String str = " tHis  strIng is  rEalLy mEssy  ";
   str =str.replace(" ", "");
   System.out.println(str);
```

output:

```
tHisstrIngisrEalLymEssy
```

For capitalizing first letter in each word there is no in-built function available, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java) has possible solutions.

Comment: This does not fix the casing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
```