# formatting textfields in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I would like to ask how to capitalize first letter entered on textfields? example when entering his last name, the first letter will be capitalized.

**samles texfields**
delos reyes | << sample text field and the result should be like this >> |Delos Reyes |

I'm using textfields from netbeans.

Comment: This can be solved using a DocumentFilter, but would involve a little work on your part.

Comment: Have a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how a NetBeans textfield is different from any other, I assume it's just a JTextField.

Extend a JTextField with your own class and override the insertString method from the Document, like in the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html).

Or, you could add a [listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield) to your textfield (actually, the underlying document) an update the String accordingly.