# displaytag in Struts2 is unable to find the properties with capitalized first letter

Tags: struts2, displaytag, ognl

When I'm displaying the properties with name user_id its perfectly showing. But If I want to display the values like "User_id " its prompting to cant find the property (NOMETHODFOUND EXCEPTION)

and also Inappropriate OGNL expression: (d - 49216) - s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to Struts2, and definitely not related to DisplayTag.

This is about OGNL and JavaBeans Naming Conventions.

As described in the [JavaBeans PDF by SUN](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf?AuthParam=1353491871_1f7e93f4935c1b11133ecc79a3c7be72),

> **8.3 Design Patterns for Properties**
>
> **8.3.1 Simple properties**
>
> By default, we use design patterns to locate properties by looking for methods of the form:
>
> ```
> public <PropertyType> get<PropertyName>();
> public void set<PropertyName>(<PropertyType> a);
> ```
>
> If we discover a matching pair of `“get<PropertyName>”` and
>   `“set<PropertyName>”` methods that take and return the same type, then
>   we regard these methods as defining a read-write property whose name
>   will be `“<propertyName>”`.  We will use the `“get<PropertyName>”`
>   method to get the property value and the `“set<PropertyName>”` method
>   to set the property value. The pair of methods may be located either
>   in the same class or one may be in a base class and the other may be
>   in a derived class.
>
> If we find only one of these methods, then we regard it as defining
>   either a read-only or a writeonly property called `“<propertyName>”`
>
> By default we assume that properties are neither bound nor constrained
>   (see Section 7).
>
> So a simple read-write property “foo” might be
>   represented by a pair of methods:
>
> ```
> public Wombat getFoo();
> public void setFoo(Wombat w);
> ```
>
> **8.3.2 Boolean properties**
>
> In addition, for boolean properties, we allow a getter method to match
>   the pattern:
>
> ```
> public boolean is<PropertyName>();
> ```
>
> This `“is<PropertyName>”` method may be provided instead of a
>   `“get<PropertyName>”` method, or it may be provided in addition to a
>   `“get<PropertyName>”` method.
>
> In either case, if the
>   `“is<PropertyName>”` method is present for a boolean property then we
>   will use the `“is<PropertyName>”` method to read the property value.
>   An example boolean property might be:
>
> ```
> public boolean isMarsupial();
> public void setMarsupial(boolean m);
> ```

---

Please read about [Java Naming Conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_conventions_%28programming%29#Java) and [CamelCase practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) too.

---

That said, your property `user_id` (that should be named by convention `userId`), has a getter like `public String getUser_id()` (if it is a String, but an ID should not be a String);

this means that you get it from OGNL with "user_id", and not with "User_id".

If the result you are trying to achieve is to capitalize the CONTENT of user_id variable,
then you should go for another way (another getter with capitalized result, like getUser_idCapitalized, or a static call from OGNL to a funcion like WordUtils.capitalize(str) by Apache, like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java), etc...

Comment: Thanks that made me clear ! Thanks a lot I  try to follow the convention