# Difference between String.valueOf(long a) and concatenating ("" + a)

Tags: java

Which approach is better and why ?

If I write

```
cmissValue = String.valueOf(callDBDatasource.cMiss());
```

or

```
cmissValue = "" + callDBDatasource.cMiss();
```

What should be the approach?

Comment: I would guess long from the title

Comment: The second one creates more `String`'s I think. But you could easily prove it yourself.

Comment: Well they are both null-safe, as far as i can see, in that cmissValue will not be null. Whether that is meaningful or intended in the context of the problem, I can not say :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
"" + callDBDatasource.cMiss();
```

Will compile to:

```
new StringBuilder().append("").append(callDBDatasource.cMiss()).toString();
```

This will create a new object and is therefore **significantly** slower. See this question: [Is string concatenaion really that slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177987/is-string-concation-really-that-slow)

Comment: The compiler doesn't detect cases like `foo = "" + bar;` and convert them to `foo = bar.toString()`?

Comment: if `bar` is a primitive data-type (like `int`), it doesn't have a `toString()`-method.

Comment: How about converting it to `foo = String.valueOf(bar)` then?

Comment: @AmitG: take a look at my answer below to see the bytecode produced by both apporaches.

Comment: @cdmckay Great answer!! then where is string pool ?? Why java is taking now `StringBuilder` help? Now I will study on that..

Answer (score 3):

This will be useful here (section "Converting numbers to Strings"): http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/newbies.php

Shortly:

```
    String.valueOf(callDBDatasource.cMiss());
```

Comment: a simpler summary for beginners please

Comment: Go to the link and search for "Converting numbers to Strings" it is few lines long. I left it here because it might be usefull for other problems and there was no answer when I started writing it.

Answer (score 2):

For those interested, I've modelled both cases and generated bytecode for them.

Here's a program for the first case:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long l = new Random().nextLong();
    String s = String.valueOf(l);
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

...and here's the bytecode:

```
0:  new             #2; //class java/util/Random
3:  dup
4:  invokespecial   #3; //Method java/util/Random."<init>":()V
7:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/util/Random.nextLong:()J
10: lstore_1
11: lload_1
12: invokestatic    #5; //Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/String;
15: astore_3
16: getstatic       #6; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
19: aload_3
20: invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
23: return
```

Which is what you would expect.

Now, here's a program modelling the second case:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long l = new Random().nextLong();
    String s = "" + l;
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

...and here's the bytecode:

```
0:  new             #2;  //class java/util/Random
3:  dup
4:  invokespecial   #3;  //Method java/util/Random."<init>":()V
7:  invokevirtual   #4;  //Method java/util/Random.nextLong:()J
10: lstore_1
11: new             #5;  //class java/lang/StringBuilder
14: dup
15: invokespecial   #6;  //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
18: ldc             #7;  //String 
20: invokevirtual   #8;  //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
23: lload_1
24: invokevirtual   #9;  //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(J)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
27: invokevirtual   #10; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
30: astore_3
31: getstatic       #11; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
34: aload_3
35: invokevirtual   #12; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
38: return
```

As you can see, many more bytecodes are produced than the first case.  You can also see (at 11 through 27) that a `StringBuilder` is used to concatenate the values, as mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: damn, I was just seconds away from posting it myself. Well, proves my right anyways :D