# UTF-8 response with servlet

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8

I am reading HTTP response from a Perl page in a Servlet like this:

```
public String getHTML(String urlToRead) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        BufferedReader rd;
        String line;
        String result = "";
        try {
           url = new URL(urlToRead);
           conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
           conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
           conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");

           rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
           while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
              byte [] b = line.getBytes();
              result += new String(b, "UTF-8");
           }
           rd.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
   }
```

I am displaying this result with this code:

```
response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"), true);


        try {

            String query = request.getParameter("query");
            String type = request.getParameter("type");

            String res = getHTML(url);
            out.write(res);

        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
```

But the response still is not encoded as UTF-8. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your PrintWriter, is it possible that "UTF8" doesn't exists but "UTF-8" do?

Comment: I tried to change it with no avail (edited)

Comment: How can you tell it's not UTF-8?

Comment: What proof do you have that `urlToRead` is returning its content in UTF-8? As that's what you're assuming it is. And why are you converting `line` to `byte`s when you already have a `String`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That call to `line.getBytes()` looks suspicious. You should probably make it `line.getBytes("UTF-8")` if you are certain that what is returned is UTF-8 encoded. Additionally, I'm not sure why it is even necessary. A typical approach to getting data out of a `BufferedReader` is to use a `StringBuilder` to continue appending each `String` retrieved from `readLine` into a result. The conversion back and forth between `String` and `byte[]` is unnecessary.

Change `result` into a `StringBuilder` and do this:

```
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `StringBuilder`. What you have currently is painfully slow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177987/is-string-concation-really-that-slow

Comment: I had originally used StringBuilder. But since it was not working, I tried to change the code according to whatever the posts on the forum suggested.

Comment: Okay. I changed it back to StringBuilder and it works now. I do not know why it did not work previously. Thank you so much for your answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is where you break the chain of character encoding conversions:

```
       while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          byte [] b = line.getBytes();  // NOT UTF-8
          result += new String(b, "UTF-8");
       }
```

From String#getBytes() javadoc:

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's
>   default charset, storing the result into a new byte array

And, defaullt charset is probably not UTF-8.

But why do all the conversions in the first place? Just read the raw bytes from the source and write the raw bytes to the consumer. It's supposed to be UTF-8 all the way.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem in another scenario, but just do it I believe it will work:

```
byte[] b = line.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET);
```

in the while loop:

```
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          byte [] b = line.getBytes();  // NOT UTF-8
          result += new String(b, "UTF-8");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have do add **another configuration**.

Previously, I was writing the page this way:

```
try (PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(response.getOutputStream()) {
        printStream.print(pageInjecting);
}
```

I changed to:

```
try (PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(response.getOutputStream(), false, "UTF-8")) {
        printStream.print(pageInjecting);
}
```