# how to get other than english text as response using java

Tags: java, utf-8, response

I am getting response from Wikipedia page and paste the response in html file. If I open the html file in browser I am not able to get the languages other than English as it is (I used UTF-8). I am attaching the picture of languages as in html.

[image]

I tried in couple of ways to get the response using java, and they are as follows,

Way 1,

```
    URL url = new URL ("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachin_Tendulkar");
    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64("root:pass".getBytes());
    //System.out.println("Host --------"+url.getHost());
    String encoding = new String (encodedBytes);

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
    connection.setDoInput (true);
    connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
    connection.connect();

    InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader in   = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));
    String line;

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String s = line.toString();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

I also tried the following code, but this also not showing the fonts as it is in 
wiki,

```
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection conn;
            BufferedReader rd;
            String line;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            try {
               url = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachin_Tendulkar");
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");

               rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
               while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                  byte [] b = line.getBytes("UTF-8");
                  result.append(line);
                  System.out.println(result.append(line));
               }
               rd.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Windows / Linux / OS X / IDE console? Do the non-ASCII chars show correctly on the console?

Comment: When you request data in `UTF-8` you should also use that encoding. `new InputStreamReader(content)` uses whatever default encoding your system has. Use `new InputStreamReader(content, "UTF-8")` instead. When you have a `String`, append it as-is to your `StringBuilder` instead of converting it to a `byte[]` array…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of points:

- Your code does not show how exactly you persist the response to the HTML file. Do you just redirect the standard output of the process to a file? Make sure you use UTF-8 even while writing to the output file.
- Why do you System.out.println the whole StringBuffer instance in each iteration of the read loop?
- Why do you call line.getBytes() and never use the output?

EDIT - Based on your comments, I really think the problem is with the clipboard manipulation. Try the code below, which stores the response directly to an output file.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HtmlDownloader {

    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    private static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";

    public boolean download(String urlAddress, String outputFileName) {
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        BufferedInputStream is = null;
        BufferedOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlAddress);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", ENCODING);
            is = new BufferedInputStream(
                    con.getInputStream()
            );
            os = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(outputFileName)
            );
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (os != null) {
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HtmlDownloader d = new HtmlDownloader();
        if (d.download("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachin_Tendulkar", "c:\\wiki.html"))
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        else
            System.out.println("FAIL");
    }
}
```

Comment: For now, I am just copying the console ( which is html response ) and paste it in editor and save it as html. Then I open the html file in browser. This is why I am making sysout.

Comment: And for your last point, I am getting reference from this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868314/utf-8-response-with-servlet

Comment: I suspect the encoding problem could arise from the clipboard manipulation or the configuration of your editor which you use for saving the file. Try saving the data from Java and see if it works.

Comment: I updated my question with other way I tried. Pls can you look in that?

Comment: It’s a nice idea to use a variable like `ENCODING` but you should use it consistently, i.e. specify it as `"Accept-Charset"` rather than keeping the literal `"UTF-8"` there. But when you read and write using the same encoding, the double conversion becomes nonsensical. Just copy the bytes directly from the `InputStream` to the `OutputStream` without the unnecessary conversions… Btw., if the target is a file, you need [a single method invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) for that.

Comment: Based on Helger's comments, I've removed the reader and the writer, which were not really necessary since we only need to copy the bytes.

Comment: You probably don't have write permissions to write directly to the C drive. Try changing the directory to some place you have access.

Comment: In fact I am trying to add this response for my next jsp, instead of making html file. For that, I need to make stringbuilder and pass it to other jsp. Is that possible?