# Capitalization of the words in string

Tags: java, arrays, split, substring

How can I avoid of StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in case when string starts with space (" ") or when there're several spaces in the string?
Actually I need to capitalize first letters of the words in the string.

My code looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = reader.readLine();
    String[] array = s.split(" ");

    for (String word : array) {
        word = word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1); //seems that here's no way to avoid extra spaces
        System.out.print(word + " ");
    }
}
```

Tests:

Input: `"test test test"`

Output: `"Test Test Test"`

---

Input:   `"  test   test  test"`

Output:

```
StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Expected:     `"  Test   Test  test"`

I'm a Java newbie and any help is very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you could check if the `String` is empty by using `String#isEmpty` and do nothing if it is.

Comment: you could use the trim() to trim the leading and trailing spaces if any

Comment: replace reader.readline() with reader.readline().trim() and then try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight modification to [Capitalize first word of a sentence in a string with multiple sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078479/capitalize-first-word-of-a-sentence-in-a-string-with-multiple-sentences).

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = reader.readLine();

    int pos = 0;
    boolean capitalize = true;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    while (pos < sb.length()) {
        if (sb.charAt(pos) == ' ') {
            capitalize = true;
        } else if (capitalize && !Character.isWhitespace(sb.charAt(pos))) {
            sb.setCharAt(pos, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(pos)));
            capitalize = false;
        }
        pos++;
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

I would avoid using split and go with StringBuilder instead.

Answer (score 1):

`split` will try to break string in each place where delimiter is found. So if you split on space and space if placed at start of the string like

```
" foo".split(" ")
```

you will get as result array which will contain two elements: empty string "" and "foo"

```
["", "foo"]
```

Now when you call `"".substring(0,1)` or `"".substring(1)` you are using index `1` which doesn't belong to that string.

So simply before you do any String modification based on indexes check if it is safe by testing string length. So check if word you are trying to modify has length grater than 0, or use something more descriptive like `if(!word.isEmpty())`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting the string, try to simply iterate over all characters within the original string, replacing all characters by its uppercase in case it's the first character of this string or if its predecessor is a space.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex in your split split all whitespaces

```
String[] words = s.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier would be to use existing libraries: [`WordUtils.capitalize(str)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html) (from [apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)).

---

To fix your current code however, a possible solution would be to use a regex for words (`\\w`) and a combination of `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder` `setCharAt` and `Character.toUpperCase`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "test test   test";

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(test);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+\\w"); // Matches 1 or more spaces followed by 1 word
    Matcher m = p.matcher(sb);

    // Since the sentence doesn't always start with a space, we have to replace the first word manually
    sb.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(0)));
    while (m.find()) {
      sb.setCharAt(m.end() - 1, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(m.end() - 1)));
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Output:

```
Test Test   Test
```

Answer (score 0):

**Capitalize whole words in String using native Java streams**

It is really elegant solution and doesnt require 3rd party libraries

```
    String s = "HELLO, capitalized worlD! i am here!     ";
    CharSequence wordDelimeter = " ";

    String res = Arrays.asList(s.split(wordDelimeter.toString())).stream()
          .filter(st -> !st.isEmpty())
          .map(st -> st.toLowerCase())
          .map(st -> st.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase().concat(st.substring(1)))
          .collect(Collectors.joining(wordDelimeter.toString()));

    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(res);
```

The output is

```
HELLO, capitalized worlD! i am here!     
Hello, Capitalized World! I Am Here!
```