# Trying To Capatalize Each Word In A String In Java

Tags: java, installation, apache-commons, configure, lang

I'm trying to capitalize the first character of each word in a string in Java. Yes I've done my research, I found this [How to capitalize the first character of each word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java). I've downloaded the binaries but I have no clue how to install them. So how do I install Lang https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/. 
Thank you,
SQL :P

EDIT: I'm using Eclipse. I wish to use the method capitalizeFully() that is in WordUtils. How would I do this?

Comment: Install where? Into your IDE? If so, what do you use (Eclipse, Netbeans, etc)?

Comment: http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/01/how-to-install-java-libraries/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download latest version of [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) `commons-lang3-version-bin.zip`

Currenly [commons-lang3-3.1-bin.zip](http://mirror.metrocast.net/apache//commons/lang/binaries/commons-lang3-3.1-bin.zip)

Place the jar file `commons-lang3-version.jar` in your class path and

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.WordUtils;
```

in your class

Finally use

`WordUtils.capitalize(str)` or `WordUtils.capitalizeFully(str)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer it  worked and also made me realize that when ever someone answers me in a forum or something I always forget to do the big part directly in the middle of the post.

Answer (score 0):

write the code yourself. Look at the java docs for the string class. 
mystring.charAt(index).toUpperCase

Comment: OP will need to split original string into words first. Then apply your code assigning the result to a new string. Then concatenate words back into a string.

Comment: True, I was just trying to give him a head start into looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When you got the Space in string using charAt(index) , You can make index+1 char in Capital by charAt(index).toCapital