# How do I take specific characters in a string and uppercase them? -- Java

Tags: java, substring, text-files

For this program, I have to read full names in from a .txt file and capitalize the first letter of the first name and the first letter of the surname.

Ex. john brown ----> John Brown

The program must also concatenate the results so that

John Brown -----> JNBN

How would I go about doing this? I have no clue how to do this. I'm brand new to Java.

Comment: where is your sample input? Is it one name per line? Have you tried this yourself? If so, where are you stuck?

Comment: What did you try? Also what is the rule for John Brown -----> JNBN (first/last ?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capitalize First Char of Each Word in a String Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java)

Comment: Apache Commons is to the rescue on this again. Check out the duplicate link

Answer (score 3):

just use the toUpperCase() command

Comment: toUpperCase() reads in files, and does the things he listed in his question?

Comment: @austinwernli - I think they were not providing the total solution but rather a direction to look at

Comment: he didn't tell what toUpperCase() so technically maybe ;)

Comment: lol you got me there @RC... Well played! Looking at this though, this does solve the question in the title. I apologize for jumping at giving this a minus 1