# How to create a private method which takes String in any uppercase/lowercase combination and return only the first letter uppercased

Tags: java

List item

How can I create a private method called "niceLetters" which takes String in any uppercase/lowercase combination and return only the first letter uppercased and all other letters lowercased?

e.g.

1.) niceLetters("stEPheN") returns "Stephen"

2.) niceLetters("HELLO") returns "Hello"

3.)niceLEtters(null) returns null

4.)niceLetters("") returns ""

Comment: StackOverFlow is not a place where you ask people to do your homework.This kind of question is not only obviously a homework question but also quite trivial and show you have not researched the answer before posting here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capitalize First Char of Each Word in a String Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java)

Comment: you're such a genius. It's not homework and I did research the answer with no success.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String niceLetters(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (str.trim().length() <= 1) {
        return str.trim().toUpperCase();
    }

    return (Character.toUpperCase(str.trim().charAt(0))+str.trim().substring(1).toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: No explanation and it doesn't actually match the specified name for the method.

Comment: @ryanyuyu OP anyway expects to be spoonfed.. not in the mood to explain