# How to return user input (string) to where only the first letter is capitalized

Tags: java, string, grammar, punctuation

Such as

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

String  productName1, productName2;
System.out.println("First product's info: ");
System.out.print("Product name: ");
productName1 = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Second product's info: ");
System.out.print("Product name: ");
```

How would I go about making it to where, when the user, per-say, types in aPPles as productName1.
When i reprint it later, how would I make the system print it was Apples. 
User input print :aPPles
reprint: Apples

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capitalize First Char of Each Word in a String Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) String class contains a lot of usefull methods like `substring` `toUpperCase` `toLowerCase`.

Comment: Yeah but it all seems like there had to be an easier way rather than just        System.out.print("|" + productName1.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + productName1.substring(1) + productname1.substring(1,4) + productName1.subtring(4);

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
productName1 = productName1.toLowerCase();  //To lower case
productName1 = productName1.substring(0,1).toUpperCase().concat(productName1.substring(1));
```

This first takes the string and makes it lower case. Then it takes the first letter, makes it uppercase and adds rest of the string to it.

Comment: Thanks! What does concat do?

Comment: It is the same as adding Strings, or connecting them together. For example, `"Dancing".concat("Dylan")` will return the String DancingDylan.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String  productName1;
    System.out.println("First product's info: ");
    System.out.print("Product name: ");
    productName1 = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Product name: ");
    productName1 = productName1.toLowerCase();
    productName1 = Character.toUpperCase(productName1.charAt(0)) + productName1.substring(1);
    System.out.println(productName1);
    keyboard.close();

}
```