# Android - How can I label my button to be small caps from the first letter of the label onwards?

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm having trouble labelling my button controls small letters from the first letter to the last. The first letter is always a capital letter? How can I change that? or should I make pictures on the ImageButton widget?

Answer (score 1):

For setting Image and label on the same control, you can use `<Button>` control of android.

**For users who just want to put Background, Icon-Image and Text in one Button from different files: Set on a Button background, drawableTop/Bottom/Right/Left and padding attributes.**

```
      <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/imagebackground"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/imageonTop"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/btnwithImage"
        android:paddingTop="32sp"
        android:drawablePadding="-15sp"
        android:text="Your Label">
     </Button>
```

You can programmatically stop all letters to become capital by below code:

```
btnwithImage.setTransformationMethod(null);
```

and you can also use:

```
android:textAllCaps="false"
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `android:textAllCaps="false"` to your button to make the button not capitalize every letter. (then set the text to however you want the capitalization : 'Button', 'button', 'BuTtOn', 'buttoN', etc.)

---

also to programmatically capitalize the first letter of a string (if that is what you are asking)

```
String yourString = "button label";
yourString = capitalize(yourString);

...

private String capitalize(final String line) {
   return Character.toUpperCase(line.charAt(0)) + line.substring(1);
}
```

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11149580

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about android since you are using jQuery so it can be done like this in jQuery

```
$('selector').css('text-transform','lowercase');
```

Note : `selector` can be a ID or class or tag_name

for e.x :

You have button like this

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

Then your jQuery will be

```
$('button').css('text-transform','lowercase');
```

This will apply style to all buttons tags...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that only on graphical layout does your font appear in capital letters when I ran it on the emmulator it was small letters as intended, thanx for your replies..!