# How to capitalize the first letter of a string in a sentence?

Tags: java, string

I can't seem to find any solutions for this with just using `String` methods in Java. Having trouble trying to get the string out...

Heres my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lab5_4
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
        String s= scan.nextLine();
        String s2 = s.toLowerCase();

        for( int count = 0; count<= s2.length()-1; count++)
        {
            if( s2.charAt(count)==' ')
            {
                String s3 = s2.substring(count,count+1);
                String s4= s3.toUpperCase();
                System.out.print(s4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What output do you get? What do you expect to get?

Comment: Possible Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/how-to-capitalize-the-first-character-of-each-word-in-a-string

Answer (score 2):

The following method forces all characters in the input string into lower case (as described by the rules of the default `Locale`) unless it is immediately preceded by an "actionable delimiter" in which case the character is coerced into upper case.

```
public static String toDisplayCase(String s) {

    final String ACTIONABLE_DELIMITERS = " '-/"; // these cause the character following
                                                 // to be capitalized
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean capNext = true;

    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        c = (capNext)
                ? Character.toUpperCase(c)
                : Character.toLowerCase(c);
        sb.append(c);
        capNext = (ACTIONABLE_DELIMITERS.indexOf((int) c) >= 0); // explicit cast not needed
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**TEST VALUES**

> a string
>
> maRTin o'maLLEY
>
> john wilkes-booth
>
> YET ANOTHER STRING

**OUTPUTS**

> A String
>
> Martin O'Malley
>
> John Wilkes-Booth
>
> Yet Another String

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be checking for a whitespace and then calling `toUpperCase()` on that. You want s3 to be the next character, so it should be `String s3 = s2.substring(count+1, count+2);`.

You are also only printing characters where the `if` is evaluated as true instead of all characters. You need the print statement to be outside the `if`. This will require more than basic changes, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pattern to select the first letter from each sentence
here an exemple

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
        String s= scan.nextLine();
        String toCappital = capitalTheFirstLetter(s);
        System.out.println(toCappital);

    }

    public static String capitalTheFirstLetter(String sentence){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(sentence.toLowerCase());
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s?([a-z])[a-z]*"); // ([a-z]) to group the first letter
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence.toLowerCase()); 
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String fistLetterToCapital = matcher.group(1).toUpperCase();
            stringBuilder.replace(matcher.start(1), matcher.end(1), fistLetterToCapital); // replace the letter with it capital
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

the output

```
Enter a sentence
how to capitalize the first letter of a string in a sentence ?
How To Capitalize The First Letter Of A String In A Sentence ?
```