# How to return words changed to upper case

Tags: java

With for loop and if else statement I have already changed the initial character of words to upper case.

I would like to know how to store the value into the x variable so that it can return to main and print it out.

The output suppose to be "The Simpson Series" instead of "the simpson series".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu2nZ.png)

Thank you.

```
package tt5;

public class StringCharacter {

public static String capitalize(String x){

//check character length
for(int i=0; i<x.length(); i++){
   Character temp = x.charAt(i);
   boolean b1 = Character.isLetter(temp);

//change words to uppercase if condition matched
    if(i==0){
        String y = temp.toString();
        String a = y.toUpperCase();
    }
    else if(b1==false){
            temp = x.charAt(i+1);
            String y = temp.toString();
            String a = " " + y.toUpperCase();
            i++;
    }
    else{
            String a = temp.toString();
    }
}

//return result
String a = "";
x = x.concat(a);
return x;
}

//input words and print the result
public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "the simpson series";
    String total = capitalize(str);
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

}

Comment: how can your question be tagged javascript and java ? And you just need to declare your String a before the for loop (don't assign "" to it after the loop)

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? And what is not working?

Comment: In case you want to start each word inside the string with a capital letter, see this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/how-to-capitalize-the-first-character-of-each-word-in-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1: StringBuilder

```
public class Capitalize {
    public static String capitalize(String string) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(string.length());

        boolean capitalizeNext = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            char c = string.charAt(i);

            if (capitalizeNext && Character.isLetter(c)) {
                c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
                capitalizeNext = false;
            } else if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                capitalizeNext = true;
            }

            builder.append(c);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    //input words and print the result
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "the simpson series";
        String total = capitalize(str);
        System.out.println(total);
    }   
}
```

### Solution 2: streams

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Capitalize {
    public static String stream(String text) {
        return Arrays.stream(text.split("\\s+"))
            .map(s -> s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }

    public static void main(String...string) {
        System.out.println(stream("the simpson series"));
    }
}
```

(although, technically, it skips multiple whitespaces into a single space)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

    String s ="the anupam singh";
    s=test(s);
    System.out.println(s);

    }


    public static String test(String s)
    {
        char c;

        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
          c=s.charAt(i);

          if(i==0)
          {
            c=Character.toUpperCase(c);
            s=c+s.substring(1,s.length());
          }
          else
          {
            if(c==' ')
            {
                c=s.charAt(i+1);
                c=Character.toUpperCase(c);
                s=s.substring(0,i+1)+c+s.substring(i+2,s.length());
            }

          }

        }

        return s;


    }


}
```

I hope you were trying to change the initial character of every word into uppercase character. I have written code for that. It's working.

Coming to your question of storing it into x variable. make string x external and then you can access it from both the methods i.e main and capitalize.

Comment: What happens with multiple spaces between words in your code? What happens if the string ends with a space?

Comment: i didn't think about the corner cases. I just gave the user a basic idea on how to do this. these corner cases can be handled easily.

Answer (score 0):

`split` each word of the given line of `String` by `\\s+` (space) and later capitalize first character of each word and append them using  `StrinBuilder`

```
public static String toTitleCase(String givenString) {
    String[] arr = givenString.split("\\s+");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(arr[i].charAt(0)))
            .append(arr[i].substring(1)).append(" ");
    }          
    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: (has the same issue with my streams solution, skipping multiple whitespaces)