# convert to capital letter using java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a List of strings like this "Taxi or bus driver". I need to convert first letter of each word to capital letter except the word "or" . Is there any easy way to achieve this using Java stream.
I have tried with Pattern.compile.splitasstream technique, I could not concat all splitted tokens back to form the original string
any help will be appreciated.If any body needs I can post my code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ConvertToCapitalUsingStreams {
    // collection holds all the words that are not to be capitalized
    private static final List<String> EXCLUSION_LIST = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"or"});

    public String convertToInitCase(final String data) {
        String[] words = data.split("\\s+");
        List<String> initUpperWords = Arrays.stream(words).map(word -> {
            //first make it lowercase
            return word.toLowerCase();
        }).map(word -> {
            //if word present in EXCLUSION_LIST return the words as is
            if (EXCLUSION_LIST.contains(word)) {
                return word;
            }

            //if the word not present in EXCLUSION_LIST, Change the case of
            //first letter of the word and return
            return Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // convert back the list of words into a single string
        String finalWord = String.join(" ", initUpperWords);

       return finalWord;
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        System.out.println(new ConvertToCapitalUsingStreams().convertToInitCase("Taxi or bus driver"));

    }
}
```

Note:
You may also want to look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/how-to-capitalize-the-first-character-of-each-word-in-a-string) post about using apache commons-text library to do this job.

Comment: This solution fitting for my requirement

Answer (score 5):

You need the right pattern to identify the *location* where a change has to be made, a zero-width pattern when you want to use `splitAsStream`. Match location which are

- a word start
- looking at a lower case character
- not looking at the word “or”

Declare it like

```
static final Pattern WORD_START_BUT_NOT_OR = Pattern.compile("\\b(?=\\p{Ll})(?!or\\b)");
```

Then, using it to process the tokens is straight-forward with a stream and `map`. Getting a string back works via `.collect(Collectors.joining())`:

```
List<String> input  = Arrays.asList("Taxi or bus driver", "apples or oranges");
List<String> result = input.stream()
    .map(s -> WORD_START_BUT_NOT_OR.splitAsStream(s)
        .map(w -> Character.toUpperCase(w.charAt(0))+w.substring(1))
        .collect(Collectors.joining()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
Taxi or Bus Driver
Apples or Oranges
```

Note that when splitting, there will always be a first token, regardless of whether it matched the criteria. Since the word “or” usually never appears at the beginning of a phrase and the transformation is transparent to non-lowercase letter characters, this should not a problem here. Otherwise, treating the first element specially with a stream would make the code too complicated. If that’s an issue, a loop would be preferable.

A loop based solution could look like

```
private static final Pattern FIRST_WORD_CHAR_BUT_NOT_OR
                           = Pattern.compile("\\b(?!or\\b)\\p{Ll}");
```

(now using a pattern that matches the character rather than looking at it)

```
public static String capitalizeWords(String phrase) {
    Matcher m = FIRST_WORD_CHAR_BUT_NOT_OR.matcher(phrase);
    if(!m.find()) return phrase;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    do m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group().toUpperCase()); while(m.find());
    return m.appendTail(sb).toString();
}
```

which, as a bonus, is also capable of handling characters which span multiple `char` units. Starting with Java 9, the `StringBuffer` can be replaced with `StringBuilder` to increase the efficiency. This method can be used like

```
List<String> result = input.stream()
    .map(s -> capitalizeWords(s))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Replacing the lambda expression `s -> capitalizeWords(s)` with a method reference of the form `ContainingClass::capitalizeWords` is also possible.

Comment: oh damn, was about to hit submit with a pattern close to that :|

Comment: Hi #Holger the first part of the solution  is not working as expected, it is not converting to upper case.

Comment: Or, with java9's [`Matcher.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-), `FIRST_WORD_CHAR_BUT_NOT_OR.matcher(phrase).replaceAll(mr->mr.group().toUpperCase())`

Comment: @PhilipPuthenvila there was a typo in the regex, it looked for upper case letters instead of lowercase. I've fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Split your string as words then convert first character to uppercase, then `joining` it to form original String:

```
String input = "Taxi or bus driver";
String output = Stream.of(input.split(" "))
                .map(w -> {
                     if (w.equals("or") || w.length() == 0) {
                         return w;
                     }
                     return w.substring(1) + Character.toUpperCase(w.charAt(0));
                })
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: And your reason is?

Comment: your doing an unnecessary call to `Stream#of` that internally will call `Arrays#stream`

Comment: @Eugene I would prefer `Arrays.stream` for semantic reasons. `String.split` returns an array and `Arrays.stream` is the right idiom to stream over an array. In contrast, `Stream.of(…)` is a *varargs* method which happens to be able to accept arrays due to the way, varargs have been implemented (and for compatibility with pre-Java 5 code).