# Java. Capitalizing, adding period

Tags: java, punctuation, capitalize

Working on this rookie task and need help.

This code must:
Capitalize the first letter of the first word.
Add a period (.) to the end of the sentence.
Join the words into a complete string, with spaces.
Do no other manipulation on the words.

Here is an example of what this  code should do:
INPUT "*i*", "*am*", "*super*", "*HERO*" 
OUTPUT  I am super HERO.

I thought about this in that case:

```
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import java.lang.String;

public class My {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] arr = new String[]{"i", "am", "super", "HERO"};
        StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
        //StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(".");
        for (String s : arr) {
            sj.add(s);
        }
        sj.append(".");
        sj.capitalize();
        System.out.println(sj);

}
```

But catching error at "*append*" and "*capitalize*" - cannot resolve method. Pls, help.

Comment: A `StringJoiner` does not offer methods `append` and `capitalize`, thus you get the error. Check the documentation.

Comment: `StringJoiner` is a good choice, due to the spaces he needs to add. The `.` should be added on the result of `sj.toString()`, i.e. `String result = sj.toString() + ".";`. Capitalization must be done on the first word `s`, not on the `StringJoiner`.

Comment: "catching error" isn't a problem description people can easily help with ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

A `StringJoiner` does not offer methods `append` and `capitalize`, thus you get the error. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringJoiner.html).

The `.` should be added on the result of `sj.toString()`, i.e. `String result = sj.toString() + ".";`. Capitalization must be done on the first word `s`, not on the `StringJoiner`.

---

### Solution

Here is a working snippet putting all together:

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"i", "am", "super", "HERO"};

StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
// Capitalize first word
sj.add(Character.toUpperCase(arr[0].charAt(0)) + arr[0].substring(1));
// Add the remaining words
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sj.add(arr[i]);
}
String result = sj.toString() + ".";

System.out.println(result);
```

Note that you may want to check for the edge case where there is no word in `arr` at all, i.e. where it is empty. The current code would then fail.

---

Do yourself a favor and pack the capitalize code into a small utility method:

```
private static String capitalize(String word) {
    return Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1);
}
```

Then the code is just:

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"i", "am", "super", "HERO"};

StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
// Capitalize first word
sj.add(capitalize(arr[0]));
// Add the remaining words
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sj.add(arr[i]);
}
String result = sj.toString() + ".";

System.out.println(result);
```

---

### Stream Solution

In case you like the Stream-API:

```
String result = capitalize(arr[0])
    + Arrays.stream(arr).skip(1)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
    + ".";
```

---

### StringJoiner Suffix

You can also do the addition of `"."` by using `StringJoiner`s suffix:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ", "", ".");
```

It will then automatically add the `"."` to the end, when you do `toString`.

Similar for the Stream solution:

```
Collectors.joining(" ", "", ".")
```

Comment: Nice would be to mention `new StringJoiner(" ", "", ".")` but you already paid the effort of a stream solution.

Answer (score 0):

A little example with the StringBuilder that you can check here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html, that have the append method.

For word capitalize you can check [How to capitalize the first character of each word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/how-to-capitalize-the-first-character-of-each-word-in-a-string)

**Example**

```
    String[] arr = new String[]{"i", "am", "super", "HERO"};
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (String word : arr){
        sb.append(WordUtils.capitalize(word));
    }

    sb.toString();
```

Comment: This also appears to be an example of how to use the Apache Commons WordUtils.capitalize() method. I don't think the OP wants (or is allowed) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for doing it using a StringJoiner.

```
public class My {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] arr = new String[]{"i", "am", "super", "HERO"};
    arr[0].toUpperCase();

    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");

    for (String s : arr) {

        sj.add(s);
    }
    sj.append(".");

    System.out.println(sj);
}
```

Comment: "*There is no way for doing it using a StringJoiner.*" - but you just did it with `StringJoiner`, I am kind of confused.

Comment: Note that `sj.append(".")` will result in space between the last word and the full stop. I.e. `"foo ."` instead of `"foo."`