# how to extract values from regex and printing them and also do computation on those values

Tags: java, regex

I have a string `"Spec Files:     15 passed, 5 failed, 20 total (100% completed) in 00:08:53"`.

I need to use regex and print the following:

```
Passed: 15
Failed: 5
Total: 20
```

And also need to compute and print the pass percentage. Pls help.

I'm using below code:

```
String line = "Spec Files:     15 passed, 5 failed, 20 total (100% completed) in 00:08:53";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compute anything. Show us your attempt. SO is not a write-code-for-me site.

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s+(\\D{6})");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
 while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
                 } 
Made able change and was able to print. not sure how to calculate the pass percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You need a regex that captures the 2 elements you need : text and value, then print them in the good order :

```
String line = "Spec Files:     15 passed, 5 failed, 20 total (100% completed) in 00:08:53";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s+(\\w+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2) + ": " + m.group(1));
}
/*
passed: 15
failed: 5
total: 20
```

- capitalize is not a built-in function so you can take a look at [How to capitalize the first character of each word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/how-to-capitalize-the-first-character-of-each-word-in-a-string#answers)

---

Pass %:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2) + ": " + m.group(1));
    map.put(m.group(2), Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)));
}
double passPercentage = map.get("passed") / (double) map.get("total");
System.out.println(passPercentage);
```

OR

```
    int passed = 0, total = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(2) + ": " + m.group(1));
        if (m.group(2).equals("passed")) {
            passed += Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        } else if (m.group(2).equals("total")) {
            total += Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        }
    }
    double passPercentage = passed / (double) total;
    System.out.println(passPercentage);
```

Comment: @arzo thanks. if i want to calculate the pass percentage by using these values, is there a function to do so?

Comment: @afser you could now think about voting up/accepting the answer if it fits your question ;)