# How to capitalize the first letter of a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, capitalize

I am using Java to get a `String` input from the user. I am trying to make the first letter of this input capitalized.

I tried this:

```
String name;

BufferedReader br = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

String s1 = name.charAt(0).toUppercase());

System.out.println(s1 + name.substring(1));
```

which led to these compiler errors:

- > Type mismatch: cannot convert from InputStreamReader to BufferedReader
- > Cannot invoke toUppercase() on the primitive type char

Comment: @Pontus - I disagree. For the input "abcd", the OP wants the output "Abcd". It seems pretty clear, although the question could have been better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java

Comment: character is a primitive data type in Java. You cannot dereference a primitive data type with dot(.) operator.
You have to substring the first character by 
name.substring(0,1);

Comment: Warning: In Turkic Alphabet the lowcase character **i** have two different upcase-letters, depending of the word that is meant. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

Answer (score 565):

```
String str = "java";
String cap = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
// cap = "Java"
```

With your example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    // Actually use the Reader
    String name = br.readLine();
    // Don't mistake String object with a Character object
    String s1 = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    String nameCapitalized = s1 + name.substring(1);
    System.out.println(nameCapitalized);
}
```

Comment: I think you need -1 after str.length(), otherwise you'll go out of bounds.

Comment: @dutt: No actually, that was perfectly fine too. But Rekin's modification made it perfect. ;)

Comment: commons lang is always better than writing your own function except in rare cases where you know better. If you didn't go read the commons lang java doc on the capitalize function, you shouldn't be writing your own.

Comment: @The.Laughing.Man Not everyone already has commons-lang as a dependency, this answer is useful for people who want to bring in a new dependency just for a single function

Comment: Hi, please note that this answer might yield incorrect outcome, as `str.substring(0, 1)` might return invalid unicode string - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70178612/what-are-some-ways-to-avoid-string-substring-from-returning-substring-with-inval

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57908029/72437 by @Miha_x64 is a much more accurate answer

Comment: With:
String str = "JAVA";

will return :
// cap = "JAVA"


We should ensure that lowerCase ever:

String str = "JAVA";
String cap = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
// cap = "Java"

Answer (score 341):

[`StringUtils.capitalize(..)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29)  from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)

Comment: I was using WordUtils it also has the same function but it capitalizes first letters of all the words in a sentence.

Comment: `StringUtils.capitalize( "fred from jupiter" );` produces `"Fred from jupiter"`. Easy ... :D

Comment: WordUtils.capitalizeFully() worked for me like charm as it gives: WordUtils.capitalizeFully("i am FINE") = "I Am Fine"

Comment: Just be aware that when you use this, the string is actually lowercase. I tried it on a Enum with value say "ATTACHMENT" and was hoping it to be "Attachment" . Ofcourse it didn't work since it capitalized the first letter "A", which was already capital ;). So first convert your string to lowercase and then use this function. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 146):

#### The shorter/faster version code to capitalize the first letter of a String is:

```
String name  = "stackoverflow"; 
name = name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

the value of `name` is `"Stackoverflow"`

Comment: I like this solution because it makes sure the rest of the string is lower-case. That's what I needed when converting from ALL_CAPS enum names.

Comment: There is a problem with your solution. There's a sentence: "i love Obama" so it will become "I love obama", which is a bit confusing. Probably `.toLowerCase()` should be optional with a flag parameter, like `public static String capitalize(String string, boolean lowerTheRest [= false]) {...`

Answer (score 101):

## Use Apache's common library. Free your brain from these stuffs and avoid Null Pointer & Index Out Of Bound Exceptions

**Step 1:**

Import apache's common lang library by putting this in `build.gradle` dependencies

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
```

**Step 2:**

If you are sure that your string is all lower case, or all you need is to initialize the first letter, directly call

```
StringUtils.capitalize(yourString);
```

If you want to make sure that only the first letter is capitalized, like doing this for an `enum`, call `toLowerCase()` first and keep in mind that it will throw `NullPointerException` if the input string is null.

```
StringUtils.capitalize(YourEnum.STUFF.name().toLowerCase());
StringUtils.capitalize(yourString.toLowerCase());
```

Here are more samples provided by apache. it's exception free

```
StringUtils.capitalize(null)  = null
StringUtils.capitalize("")    = ""
StringUtils.capitalize("cat") = "Cat"
StringUtils.capitalize("cAt") = "CAt"
StringUtils.capitalize("'cat'") = "'cat'"
```

**Note:**

`WordUtils` is also included in this library, but is deprecated. Please **do not** use that.

Comment: WordUtils.capitalizeFully() worked for me like charm as it gives: WordUtils.capitalizeFully("i am FINE") = "I Am Fine"

Answer (score 46):

## if you use **SPRING**:

```
import static org.springframework.util.StringUtils.capitalize;
...


    return capitalize(name);
```

**IMPLEMENTATION:** [org/springframework/util/StringUtils.java#L535-L555](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/64440a5f04a17b3728234afaa89f57766768decb/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.java#L535-L555)

**REF:** [javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#capitalize](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#capitalize-java.lang.String-)

---

**NOTE:** If you already have Apache Common Lang dependency, then consider using their StringUtils.capitalize as other answers suggest.

Answer (score 45):

**Java:**

simply a helper method for capitalizing every string.

```
public static String capitalize(String str)
{
    if(str == null || str.length()<=1) return str;
    return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
}
```

After that simply call `str = capitalize(str)`

---

**Kotlin:**

```
str.capitalize()
```

Comment: need to consider empty string, otherwise will cause an index out of bound error

Comment: For string with length 1, don't do anything. Bug.

Answer (score 24):

What you want to do is probably this:

```
s1 = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
```

(converts first char to uppercase and adds the remainder of the original string)

Also, you create an input stream reader, but never read any line. Thus `name` will always be `null`.

This should work:

```
BufferedReader br = new InputstreamReader(System.in);
String name = br.readLine();
String s1 = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 19):

[`WordUtils.capitalize(java.lang.String)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

Comment: Hi! Could you please explain how to implement this in my project? I can see any file download link in your URL. Thanks

Comment: This method is deprecated. Please use StringUtils from commons-lang

Answer (score 16):

Below solution will work.

```
String A = "stackOverflow";
String ACaps = A.toUpperCase().charAt(0)+A.substring(1,A.length());
//Will print StackOverflow
```

You can't use toUpperCase() on primitive char , but you can make entire String to Uppercase first then take the first char, then to append to the substring as shown above.

Answer (score 14):

Use this utility method to capitalize the first letter of every word.

```
String capitalizeAllFirstLetters(String name) 
{
    char[] array = name.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    array[0] = Character.toUpperCase(array[0]);
 
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isWhitespace(array[i - 1])) {
            array[i] = Character.toUpperCase(array[i]);
        }
    }
 
    return new String(array);
}
```

Comment: There is a mistake in the logic. The first line of the function should be `char[] array = name.toLowerCase().toCharArray();` .  Otherwise, the function only works if you input an all-lowercase String.

Answer (score 12):

Use [`WordUtils.capitalize(str)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalize(java.lang.String)).

Comment: should also mention which library this is.

Answer (score 9):

Set the string to lower case, then set the first Letter to upper like this:

```
userName = userName.toLowerCase();
```

then to capitalise the first letter:

```
userName = userName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + userName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

substring is just getting a piece of a larger string, then we are combining them  back together.

Comment: How i get it, the first line of code, is useless, as the rest of the string is set to lower case either way.

Answer (score 9):

```
String str1 = "hello";
str1.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()+str1.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 8):

Shortest too:

```
String message = "my message";    
message = Character.toUpperCase(message.charAt(0)) + message.substring(1);
System.out.println(message)    // Will output: My message
```

Worked for me.

Comment: I have a hunch that the `charAt(0)` offers better performance than `substring(0, 1)`.

Comment: @user16217248 yes and it's more readable as well, **substring** performs some string manipulation (copy) using an array of bytes as well as index checking while **charAt** will access the target directly (bytesArray[0]).

But I believe it'll be noticeable if you perform multiple substring operations.

Answer (score 8):

**IT WILL WORK 101%**

```
public class UpperCase {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        String name;

        System.out.print("INPUT: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        name  = scan.next();

        String upperCase = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
        System.out.println("OUTPUT: " + upperCase); 

    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if one just presses "Enter"? What happens if just one letter is input?

Comment: @koppor then IT WILL WORK 0%

Answer (score 8):

Here is my detailed article on the topic for all possible options [Capitalize First Letter of String in Android](https://handyopinion.com/capitalize-first-letter-of-string-in-android-kotlin-java/)

**Method to Capitalize First Letter of String in Java**

```
public static String capitalizeString(String str) {
        String retStr = str;
        try { // We can face index out of bound exception if the string is null
            retStr = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
        }catch (Exception e){}
        return retStr;
}
```

**Method to Capitalize First Letter of String in KOTLIN**

```
fun capitalizeString(str: String): String {
        var retStr = str
        try { // We can face index out of bound exception if the string is null
            retStr = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
        return retStr
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also try this:

```
String s1 = br.readLine();
char[] chars = s1.toCharArray();
chars[0] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[0]);
s1= new String(chars);
System.out.println(s1);
```

This is better (optimized) than with using substring. (but not to worry on small string)

Answer (score 6):

**In Android Studio**

Add this dependency to your `build.gradle (Module: app)`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
    ...
}
```

Now you can use

```
String string = "STRING WITH ALL CAPPS AND SPACES";

string = string.toLowerCase(); // Make all lowercase if you have caps

someTextView.setText(WordUtils.capitalize(string));
```

Answer (score 6):

What about [WordUtils.capitalizeFully()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully-java.lang.String-)?

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String str1 = "HELLO WORLD";
        System.out.println(capitalizeFirstLetter(str1)); // output: Hello World

        final String str2 = "Hello WORLD";
        System.out.println(capitalizeFirstLetter(str2)); // output: Hello World

        final String str3 = "hello world";
        System.out.println(capitalizeFirstLetter(str3)); // output: Hello World

        final String str4 = "heLLo wORld";
        System.out.println(capitalizeFirstLetter(str4)); // output: Hello World
    }

    private static String capitalizeFirstLetter(String str) {
        return WordUtils.capitalizeFully(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution! doesn't require any external library, it can handle empty or one letter string.

```
private String capitalizeFirstLetter(@NonNull String str){
        return str.length() == 0 ? str
                : str.length() == 1 ? str.toUpperCase()
                : str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Most of the other answers  will fail when given a single letter, say, 'b' due to an ArrayOutOfBoundsException. It's a shame this solution did not explain any of the code per StackOverflow guidelines. Sure, the solution is readily apparent to somebody who's a Java veteran, but not necessarily so for somebody who's relatively new to Java.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `substring()` to do this.

But there are two different cases:

**Case 1**

If the `String` you are capitalizing is meant to be human-readable, you should also specify the default locale:

```
String firstLetterCapitalized = 
    myString.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()) + myString.substring(1);
```

**Case 2**

If the `String` you are capitalizing is meant to be machine-readable, avoid using `Locale.getDefault()` because the string that is returned will be inconsistent across different regions, and in this case always specify the same locale (for example, `toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)`).  This will ensure that the strings you are using for internal processing are consistent, which will help you avoid difficult-to-find bugs.

Note: You do not have to specify `Locale.getDefault()` for `toLowerCase()`, as this is done automatically.

Answer (score 4):

try this one

What this method does is that, Consider the word "hello world" this method turn it into "Hello World" capitalize the beginning of each word .

```
private String capitalizer(String word){

       String[] words = word.split(" ");
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       if (words[0].length() > 0) {
           sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(words[0].charAt(0)) + words[0].subSequence(1, words[0].length()).toString().toLowerCase());
           for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
               sb.append(" ");
               sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0)) + words[i].subSequence(1, words[i].length()).toString().toLowerCase());
           }
       }
       return  sb.toString();

   }
```

Comment: But this code seems pretty much understandable,All the methods are easy to understand by their names also .but thanks for your comment ,will try to make more perfect from next time ,i get too lazy some time :-) .

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

**If Input is UpperCase ,then Use following :**

str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowerCase();

**If Input is LowerCase ,then Use following :**

str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);

Answer (score 4):

Existing answers are either

- incorrect: they think that `char` is a separate character (code point), while it is a UTF-16 word which can be a half of a surrogate pair, or
- use libraries which is not bad itself but requires adding dependencies to your project, or
- [use Java 8 Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53002156/3050249) which is perfectly valid but not always possible.

Let's look at [surrogate characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+010000_to_U+10FFFF) (every such character consist of two UTF-16 words — Java `char`s) and can have upper and lowercase variants:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0x01_0000, 0x10_FFFF)
    .filter(ch -> Character.toUpperCase(ch) != Character.toLowerCase(ch))
    .forEach(ch -> System.out.print(new String(new int[] { ch }, 0, 1)));
```

Many of them may look like 'tofu' (□) for you but they are mostly valid characters of rare scripts and some typefaces support them.

For example, let's look at Deseret Small Letter Long I (), U+10428, `"\uD801\uDC28"`:

```
System.out.println("U+" + Integer.toHexString(
        "\uD801\uDC28".codePointAt(0)
)); // U+10428

System.out.println("U+" + Integer.toHexString(
        Character.toTitleCase("\uD801\uDC28".codePointAt(0))
)); // U+10400 — ok! capitalized character is another code point

System.out.println("U+" + Integer.toHexString(new String(new char[] {
        Character.toTitleCase("\uD801\uDC28".charAt(0)), "\uD801\uDC28".charAt(1)
}).codePointAt(0))); // U+10428 — oops! — cannot capitalize an unpaired surrogate
```

So, a code point can be capitalized even in cases when `char` cannot be.
Considering this, let's write a correct (and Java 1.5 compatible!) capitalizer:

```
@Contract("null -> null")
public static CharSequence capitalize(CharSequence input) {
    int length;
    if (input == null || (length = input.length()) == 0) return input;

    return new StringBuilder(length)
            .appendCodePoint(Character.toTitleCase(Character.codePointAt(input, 0)))
            .append(input, Character.offsetByCodePoints(input, 0, 1), length);
}
```

And check whether it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ASCII
    System.out.println(capitalize("whatever")); // w -> W

    // UTF-16, no surrogate
    System.out.println(capitalize("что-то")); // ч -> Ч

    // UTF-16 with surrogate pairs
    System.out.println(capitalize("\uD801\uDC28")); //  -> 
}
```

See also:

- surrogate pairs [What is a "surrogate pair" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903008/what-is-a-surrogate-pair-in-java)
- upper case vs. title case https://stackoverflow.com/a/47887432/3050249

Comment: At least a nice example on how to handle Unicode correctly. Thank you.

Comment: …but still scratching on the surface of the related problems. Case mapping is a *locale sensitive* operation and can have different results for different locales. So we have to know what the operation is for. Is it about processing code identifiers (e.g. when mapping Bean property names to getter methods) and requires a fixed locale for reproducible results or is it about user strings requiring the user’s locale? In the latter case, we need to known whether the default locale truly is the user’s locale (like in desktop applications) or we are on a server and need the client’s locale…

Answer (score 4):

Current answers are either incorrect or over-complicate this simple task. After doing some research, here are [two approaches](https://attacomsian.com/blog/capitalize-first-letter-of-string-java) I come up with:

**1. String's `substring()` Method**

```java
public static String capitalize(String str) {
    if(str== null || str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }

    return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
}
```

Examples:

```java
System.out.println(capitalize("java")); // Java
System.out.println(capitalize("beTa")); // BeTa
System.out.println(capitalize(null)); // null
```

**2. Apache Commons Lang**

The Apache Commons Lang library provides `StringUtils` the class for this purpose:

```java
System.out.println(StringUtils.capitalize("apache commons")); // Apache commons
System.out.println(StringUtils.capitalize("heLLO")); // HeLLO
System.out.println(StringUtils.uncapitalize(null)); // null
```

Don't forget to add the following dependency to your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Try another test with `StringUtils.capitalize("a")`.

Comment: This is the right one - WordUtils.initials("AsdfAsadfg Basdf"");

Comment: Try another test with StringUtils.capitalize("b") Tee-hee!!

Answer (score 3):

This is just to show you, that you were not that wrong.

```
BufferedReader br = new InputstreamReader(System.in);
// Assuming name is not blank
String name = br.readLine(); 

//No more error telling that you cant convert char to string
String s1 = (""+name.charAt(0)).toUppercase());
// Or, as Carlos prefers. See the comments to this post.
String s1 = Character.toString(name.charAt(0)).toUppercase());

System.out.println(s1+name.substring(1));
```

**Note:** *This is not at all the best way to do it. This is just to show the OP that it can be done using `charAt()` as well. ;)*

Comment: +1 for "not that wrong". I would *prefer* `Character.toString(name.charAt(0))` instead of `""+name.charAt(0)` for showing what I really want to do.

Comment: No null length checks.. Length could be zero.

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
char[] array = value.toCharArray();

array[0] = Character.toUpperCase(array[0]);

String result = new String(array);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    capitalizeFirstLetter("java");
    capitalizeFirstLetter("java developer");
}

public static void capitalizeFirstLetter(String text) {

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    String[] tokens = text.split("\\s");// Can be space,comma or hyphen

    for (String token : tokens) {
        str.append(Character.toUpperCase(token.charAt(0))).append(token.substring(1)).append(" ");
    }
    str.toString().trim(); // Trim trailing space

    System.out.println(str);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `commons.lang.StringUtils` the best answer is:

```
public static String capitalize(String str) {  
    int strLen;  
    return str != null && (strLen = str.length()) != 0 ? (new StringBuffer(strLen)).append(Character.toTitleCase(str.charAt(0))).append(str.substring(1)).toString() : str;  
}
```

I find it brilliant since it wraps the string with a StringBuffer. You can manipulate the StringBuffer as you wish and though using the same instance.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at ACL WordUtils.

WordUtils.capitalize("your string") == "Your String"

[How to upper case every first letter of word in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149855/how-to-upper-case-every-first-letter-of-word-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String capitalizer(final String texto) {

    // split words
    String[] palavras = texto.split(" ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // list of word exceptions
    List<String> excessoes = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("de", "da", "das", "do", "dos", "na", "nas", "no", "nos", "a", "e", "o", "em", "com"));

    for (String palavra : palavras) {

        if (excessoes.contains(palavra.toLowerCase()))
            sb.append(palavra.toLowerCase()).append(" ");
        else
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(palavra.charAt(0))).append(palavra.substring(1).toLowerCase()).append(" ");
    }
    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
public static String capitalizeString(String string) {

    if (string == null || string.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return string;
    }
    char c[] = string.trim().toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    c[0] = Character.toUpperCase(c[0]);

    return new String(c);

}
```

example test with JUnit:

```
@Test
public void capitalizeStringUpperCaseTest() {

    String string = "HELLO WORLD  ";

    string = capitalizeString(string);

    assertThat(string, is("Hello world"));
}

@Test
public void capitalizeStringLowerCaseTest() {

    String string = "hello world  ";

    string = capitalizeString(string);

    assertThat(string, is("Hello world"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use substrings for simple hacks ;).

```
String name;
    
String s1 = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1, name.length());

System.out.println(s1));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(Character.toString(A.charAt(0)).toUpperCase()+A.substring(1));
```

P.S = a is a string.

Comment: Alternately (using `str` instead of `A` which looks like a class name):  `str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+str.substring(1);`

Answer (score 2):

Yet another example, how you can make the first letter of the user input capitalized:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String string = br.readLine();
// handle supplementary characters
IntStream.concat(
        IntStream.of(string.codePointAt(0))
                .map(Character::toUpperCase), string.codePoints().skip(1)
)
.forEach(cp -> System.out.print(Character.toChars(cp)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you first get Char from your original string. You cant use String properties on char so just use to upper first and then use charAt

```
String s1 = name.toUppercase().charAt(0);
```

Comment: You can't  convert from char to String this way. Your answer would result in an additional type mismatch. Additional because of assigning InputStreamReader to BufferedReader won't work. I suggest to look at the other answers.

Comment: Suggest using `Character.toUpperCase()` after `charAt()` because in this case you are capitalizing a single character instead of capitalizing the entire string and only using the first character, offering better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the answers are very helpful so I used them to create a method to turn any string to a title (first character capitalized):

```
static String toTitle (String s) {
      String s1 = s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
      String sTitle = s1 + s.substring(1);
      return sTitle;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reworked Jorgesys code and **added few checks** because of few cases related to String length. Don't do for null reference check in my case.

```
 public static String capitalizeFirstLetter(@NonNull String customText){
        int count = customText.length();
        if (count == 0) {
            return customText;
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            return customText.toUpperCase();
        }
        return customText.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + customText.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To capitalize first character of each word in a string ,

first you need to get each words of that string & for this split string where any space is there using split method as below  and store each words in an Array. 
Then create an empty string.  After that by using substring() method get the first character & remaining character of corresponding word and store them in two different variables.

Then by using toUpperCase() method capitalize the first character and add the remaianing characters as below to that empty string.

```
public class Test {  
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         String str= "my name is khan";        // string
         String words[]=str.split("\\s");      // split each words of above string
         String capitalizedWord = "";         // create an empty string

         for(String w:words)
         {  
              String first = w.substring(0,1);    // get first character of each word
              String f_after = w.substring(1);    // get remaining character of corresponding word
              capitalizedWord += first.toUpperCase() + f_after+ " ";  // capitalize first character and add the remaining to the empty string and continue
         }
         System.out.println(capitalizedWord);    // print the result
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code i have posted will remove underscore(_) symbol and extra spaces from String and also it will capitalize first letter of every new word in String

```
private String capitalize(String txt){ 
  List<String> finalTxt=new ArrayList<>();

  if(txt.contains("_")){
       txt=txt.replace("_"," ");
  }

  if(txt.contains(" ") && txt.length()>1){
       String[] tSS=txt.split(" ");
       for(String tSSV:tSS){ finalTxt.add(capitalize(tSSV)); }  
  }

  if(finalTxt.size()>0){
       txt="";
       for(String s:finalTxt){ txt+=s+" "; }
  }

  if(txt.endsWith(" ") && txt.length()>1){
       txt=txt.substring(0, (txt.length()-1));
       return txt;
  }

  txt = txt.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + txt.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  return txt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the answers was 95% correct, but it failed on my unitTest @Ameen Maheen's solution was nearly perfect. Except that before the input gets converted to String array, you have to trim the input. So the perfect one:

```
private String convertStringToName(String name) {
        name = name.trim();
        String[] words = name.split(" ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (words[0].length() > 0) {
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(words[0].charAt(0)) + words[0].subSequence(1, words[0].length()).toString().toLowerCase());
            for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
                sb.append(" ");
                sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0)) + words[i].subSequence(1, words[i].length()).toString().toLowerCase());
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: This looks like the most simple solution!!

Answer (score 1):

Given answers is for capitalize the first letter of one word only. use following code to capitalize a whole string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "this is a random string";
    StringBuilder capitalizedString = new StringBuilder();
    String[] splited = str.trim().split("\\s+");

    for (String string : splited) {         
        String s1 = string.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        String nameCapitalized = s1 + string.substring(1);

        capitalizedString.append(nameCapitalized);
        capitalizedString.append(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(capitalizedString.toString().trim());
}
```

output : 
`This Is A Random String`

Answer (score 1):

Use replace method.

```
String newWord = word.replace(String.valueOf(word.charAt(0)), String.valueOf(word.charAt(0)).toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

Following example also capitalizes words after special characters such as [/-]

```
  public static String capitalize(String text) {
    char[] stringArray = text.trim().toCharArray();
    boolean wordStarted = false;
    for( int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
      char ch = stringArray[i];
      if ((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || ch == '\'') {
        if( !wordStarted ) {
          stringArray[i] = Character.toUpperCase(stringArray[i]);
          wordStarted = true;
        } 
      } else {
        wordStarted = false;
      }
    }
    return new String(stringArray);
  }

Example:
capitalize("that's a beautiful/wonderful life we have.We really-do")

Output:
That's A Beautiful/Wonderful Life We Have.We Really-Do
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks I have read some of the comments and I came with the following

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
String myName = "nasser";
String newName = myName.toUpperCase().charAt(0) +  myName.substring(1);
System.out.println(newName );
}
```

I hope its helps 
good luck

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Ameen Mahheen is good but if we have some string with double space, like "hello  world" then sb.append gets IndexOutOfBounds Exception. Right thing to do is teste before this line, doing:

```
private String capitalizer(String word){
        String[] words = word.split(" ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (words[0].length() > 0) {
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(words[0].charAt(0)) + words[0].subSequence(1, words[0].length()).toString().toLowerCase());
            for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
                sb.append(" ");
                if (words[i].length() > 0) sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0)) + words[i].subSequence(1, words[i].length()).toString().toLowerCase());
            }
        }
        return  sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
/**
 * capitilizeFirst(null)  -> ""
 * capitilizeFirst("")    -> ""
 * capitilizeFirst("   ") -> ""
 * capitilizeFirst(" df") -> "Df"
 * capitilizeFirst("AS")  -> "As"
 *
 * @param str input string
 * @return String with the first letter capitalized
 */
public String capitilizeFirst(String str)
{
    // assumptions that input parameter is not null is legal, as we use this function in map chain
    Function<String, String> capFirst = (String s) -> {
        String result = ""; // <-- accumulator

        try { result += s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(); }
        catch (Throwable e) {}
        try { result += s.substring(1).toLowerCase(); }
        catch (Throwable e) {}

        return result;
    };

    return Optional.ofNullable(str)
            .map(String::trim)
            .map(capFirst)
            .orElse("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Class WordUtils.

Suppose your String is "current address" then use

****strong text**Wordutils.capitaliz(String);**
output : Current Address

Refer: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

```
class CapitalizeWords
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String input ="welcome to kashmiri geeks...";

        System.out.println(input);

        String[] str = input.split(" ");

        for(int i=0; i< str.length; i++)
        {
            str[i] = (str[i]).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + (str[i]).substring(1);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(str[i]+" ");
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "first second third fourth";

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            if ((s.substring(j, i).endsWith(" "))) {

                String s2 = s.substring(j, i);
                System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(j))+s2.substring(1));
                j = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(j))+s.substring(j+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach.

```
String input = "someТекст$T%$4čřЭ"; //Enter your text.
if (input == null || input.isEmpty()) {
    return "";
}

char [] chars = input.toCharArray();
chars[0] = chars[0].toUpperCase();
String res = new String(chars);
return res;
```

The drawback of this method is that if inputString is long, you will have three objects of such length. The same as you do

```
String s1 = input.substring(1).toUpperCase();
String s2 = input.substring(1, lenght);
String res = s1 + s2;
```

Or even

```
//check if not null.
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(input);
char ch = buf.getCharAt(0).toUpperCase();
buf.setCharAt(0, ch);
return buf.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code to capitalize each word in text!

```
public String capitalizeText(String name) {
    String[] s = name.trim().toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
    name = "";
    for (String i : s){
        if(i.equals("")) return name; // or return anything you want
        name+= i.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + i.substring(1) + " "; // uppercase first char in words
    }
    return name.trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1=sc.nextLine();
        String[] s2=s1.split(" ");//***split text into words***
        ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();//***list***
        for(String w: s2)
        l.add(w.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+w.substring(1)); 
        //***converting 1st letter to capital and adding to list***
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();//***i used StringBuilder to convert words to text*** 
        for (String s : l)
          {
             sb.append(s);
             sb.append(" ");
          }
      System.out.println(sb.toString());//***to print output***
      }
}
```

i have used split function to split the string into words then again i took list to get the first letter capital in that words and then i took string builder to print the output in string format with spaces in it

Answer (score 0):

To capitalize the first letter of the input string, we first split the string on space and then use the collection transformation procedure provided by **map**

```
<T, R> Array<out T>.map(

   transform: (T) -> R

): List<R>
```

to transform, each split string to first in lowercase then capitalize the first letter. This map transformation will return a list that needs to convert into a string by using **joinToString** function.

> KOTLIN

```
fun main() {
    
    /*
     * Program that first convert all uper case into lower case then 
     * convert fist letter into uppercase
     */
    
    val str = "aLi AzAZ alam"
    val calStr = str.split(" ").map{it.toLowerCase().capitalize()}
    println(calStr.joinToString(separator = " "))
}
```

> OUTPUT

[image: output of above code]

Comment: The question refered to Java, not Kotlin. Java does not have that capitalize() method (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution from my side, with all the conditions check.

```
   import java.util.Objects;

public class CapitalizeFirstCharacter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(capitailzeFirstCharacterOfString("jwala")); //supply input string here
    }

    private static String capitailzeFirstCharacterOfString(String strToCapitalize) {

        if (Objects.nonNull(strToCapitalize) && !strToCapitalize.isEmpty()) {
            return strToCapitalize.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + strToCapitalize.substring(1);
        } else {
            return "Null or Empty value of string supplied";

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Those who search capitalize first letter of a name here..

```
public static String capitaliseName(String name) {
    String collect[] = name.split(" ");
    String returnName = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < collect.length; i++) {
        collect[i] = collect[i].trim().toLowerCase();
        if (collect[i].isEmpty() == false) {
            returnName = returnName + collect[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + collect[i].substring(1) + " ";
        }
    }
    return returnName.trim();
}
```

> **usase:** *capitaliseName("saurav khan");*
>
> **output:** *Saurav Khan*

Answer (score -1):

- character `char` can't store in `String`.
- `char` and `String` can't concatenate.
- `String.valueOf()` use to convert `char` to `String`

`Input`

```
india
```

`Code`

```
String name = "india";
char s1 = name.charAt(0).toUppercase()); // output: 'I'
System.out.println(String.valueOf(s1) + name.substring(1)); // output: "I"+ "ndia";
```

`Output`

```
India
```

Comment: `char` does not have `toUppercase` method

Answer (score -1):

To avoid exceptions (IndexOutOfBoundsException or NullPointerException when using substring(0, 1) for an empty or null string), you can use regex ("^.")
(since Java 9):

```
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        String name = reader.readLine();

        name = Pattern.compile("^.")    // regex for the first character of a string
                .matcher(name)
                .replaceFirst(matchResult -> matchResult.group().toUpperCase());

        System.out.println(name);
    } catch(IOException ignore) {}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
public static String capitalizeName(String name) {
    String fullName = "";
    String names[] = name.split(" ");
    for (String n: names) {
        fullName = fullName + n.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + n.toLowerCase().substring(1, n.length()) + " ";
    }
    return fullName;
}
```