# Make String first letter capital in java

Tags: java, string, capitalize

As of now I'm using this code to make my first letter in a string capital

```
String output = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
```

This seems very dirty to me ..is there any direct or elegant way..

Comment: [StringUtils.capitalize()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29)? Looking for elegance in Java is... well, there are better ROIs. Utility libraries exist for a reason.

Comment: Do you need to consider the locale? Each locale has different rules for changing the case of letters.

Comment: @erickson No need.English is enough for me.

Comment: The same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904579/capitalizing-the-first-letter-of-a-string (although this one is more clearly worded).

Answer (score 54):

How about this:

```
String output = Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(0)) + input.substring(1);
```

I can't think of anything cleaner without using external libraries, but this is definitely better than what you currently have.

Comment: I think that Marco meant, that "" or null will fail; StringUtils.capitalize will not fail on that.

Comment: @JoopEggen This has exactly the same behavior as the OP's original code, whereas `StringUtils.capitalize` does not.

Comment: I don't even undestand why this gets downvoted, in my opinion it's the best method, unless i'm missing something

Comment: `StringUtils.capitalize( "fred from jupiter" );` produces `"Fred from jupiter"`. That's all what you need!

Answer (score 31):

You should have a look at [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) lib - it has method [`.capitalize()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29)

Description from the lib:

> Capitalizes a String changing the first letter to title case as per
>   Character.toTitleCase(char). No other letters are changed.

Comment: Note that if you want to only capitalize the first letter (say, for formatting a name), you may need to lowercase the entire string before running capitalize if you suspect there may be caps in your string already.

From the JavaDoc: StringUtils.capitalize("cAt") = "CAt"

Comment: Capitalize will capitalize first letter of every single word not just the first

Comment: `StringUtils.capitalize( "fred from jupiter" );` produces `"Fred from jupiter"`.
Only the **first** char from String-object will be uppercased.

Answer (score 2):

```
String out = Character.toUpperCase(inText.charAt(0)) + inText.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = null;
    String outStr = null;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a String: ");
    str = sc.nextLine();
    //c= Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0));

    for(int i=0; i< (str.length());i++){

        if(str.charAt(i)==' '){

            outStr= outStr.substring(0,i+1)+str.substring(i+1,i+2).toUpperCase()+str.substring(i+2);

        }else if(i==0){

            outStr=str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+str.substring(1);

        }
    }
    System.out.println("STRING::"+outStr);
}
```

Comment: If I enter a string like `_123` (starting with a space), it throws a `NullPointerException`. Your answer seems also to be a bit complicated compared to the others.

Comment: well, not only that, my program should also throw NullPointerException if you add a space at the end. I have not done those checks, you can use regex if you want to... I just gave a skeleton of how this can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use Java 8, here's the functional way that nobody asked for...

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class StringHelper {
    public static String capitalize(String source) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(source)
            .map(str -> IntStream.concat(
                str.codePoints().limit(1).map(Character::toUpperCase),
                str.codePoints().skip(1)))
            .map(stream -> stream.toArray())
            .map(arr -> new String(arr, 0, arr.length))
            .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

It's elegant in that it handles the null and empty string cases without any conditional statements.

Comment: `StringUtils.capitalize( "fred from jupiter" );` produces `"Fred from jupiter"`. It's less source code ... :D

Answer (score 0):

```
Character.toString(a.charAt(0)).toUpperCase()+a.substring(1)
```

P.S = a is string.

Answer (score 0):

Here, [hold my beer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase())

```
String foo = "suresh";
String bar = foo.toUpperCase();
if(bar.charAt[0] == 'S'){
   throw new SuccessException("bar contains 'SURESH' and has the first letter capital").
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this use case and i used **StringUtils** provided by **Apache Common Lang** ([check link for more details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#capitalize-java.lang.String-)) for solving this:
so basically my use case was like this, i had to extract the firstName and lastName from User's email and after that i got the first splitted part and split again at '.'(Dot) sign and from there i got the name and lastName.

here is the code for the scenario explained above:

```
    String[] splitEmail =userDtoResponseFromHttpClient.getEmail().split("@");
    String[] username = splitEmail[0].split("\\.");
    user.setFirstName(**StringUtils.capitalize(username[0]**));
    user.setLastName(**StringUtils.capitalize(username[1]**));
```

FYI: I knew for sure that all emails would be in format **firstName.lastName**

Answer (score -2):

```
class strDemo3
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String s1=new String(" the ghost of the arabean sea");
        char c1[]=new char[30];       
        int c2[]=new int[30];
        s1.getChars(0,28,c1,0);
        for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
        {
           System.out.print(c1[i]);
        }
        for(int i=1;i<s1.length();i++)
        {
           c2[i]=c1[i];
           if(c1[i-1]==' ')
           {
               c2[i]=c2[i]-32;
           }
           c1[i]=(char)c2[i];          
        }
        for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
        {
           System.out.print(c1[i]);
        }            
       }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code that might be incomprehensible to the OP. Explain your answer step by step and give advice.

Comment: My code looks more beautiful to me now :) Thanks for the answer though.