# Is there any method in ObjectMapper to match json string with Enum

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an Enum

```
public enum status{
  YES,
  NO
}
```

the input from json string is "Yes" or "No", is there any method in ObjectMapper to match status.YES with "Yes", and status.NO with "No".

I don't want to change enum, because int my previous system, people use the enum all the time, I don't want cause problem for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always redefine it like:

```
public enum Status {
  YES("Yes"),
  NO("No");

  private final String status;

  private Status(final String status) {
    this.status = status;
  }

  public String value() {
    return this.status;
  }
}
```

And then use something like this: `Status.YES.value()`;

Comment: Thank you for your response, but is there any way I don't need change enum, because I don't mess with the enum everyone is using

Comment: If you do that you won't break anyone else code...guaranteed! Take a look. You are not changing any structure or any value(s); the only thing you need to get the value you want is to invoke the `.value()` call on any existing enum value in the actual source code

Comment: The constructor here must be private.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toString()` method available in all Java enums:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

and on returned `String` call `compareToIgnoreCase` method to compare it with input:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_comparetoignorecase.htm

Or you can call `toUpperCase` on input `String` and then comapre them:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_touppercase.htm

Finally, you can use `toString` mentioned earlier and put all letters except the first to lower case:

```
String YesString = enumWithYESValue.toString().substring(0, 1) + enumWithYESValue.toString().substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Based on: [How to capitalize the first letter of a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904579/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-java)