# OpenNlp Case Insensitive Location Finder

Tags: opennlp

I want to get the name of the locations mentioned in a sentence. Everything works fine untill a location name is found with small starting letter. 
So is there any way to solve this problem? Do I need to train my own model file? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll need to make your own model file for these type of things, which is tedious.
A simple solution would be, add some code to make the first letter capital of every token in your sentence before finding the location.
something like this,[mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904579/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-java):

```
String str = "java";
String cap = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer, an easy way out :)