# Changing upper case string to lower case, but keep only first character to Upper case

Tags: java

I have multiple strings in upper case:

JAMES SMITH, NAVIN HEMANT SIGNH, LALA UTRIZER

How can I transform these strings to:

James Smith, Navin Hemant Signh, Lala Utrizer in java?

Please help.

Comment: by writing code to do so, instead of asking for it. there are several ways to do this, all of which are extremely basic. write down a scenario in which it would possible (not code, just pseudo-code), so you have the logic, and after that, implement it

Comment: Refer the link below for the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904579/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-java

Comment: This is a duplicate question. You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/how-to-capitalize-the-first-character-of-each-word-in-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
String values = "JAMES SMITH, NAVIN HEMANT SIGNH, LALA UTRIZER";


if (values != null && !values.isEmpty()) {
    final StringBuilder fixedCaseBuilder = new StringBuilder(values.length()+1);

    for (final String word : values.split(" ")) {
        if (!word.isEmpty()) {
            fixedCaseBuilder.append(Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)));
            fixedCaseBuilder.append(word.substring(1, word.length()).toLowerCase());
        }
        fixedCaseBuilder.append(' ');
    }

    fixedCaseBuilder.setLength(fixedCaseBuilder.length()-1);
    final String result = fixedCaseBuilder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can choose what libraries to use, I would advise ***WordUtils*** from *Apache Commons Utils*. It has a method [capitalizeFully(String s)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully(java.lang.String)), which takes a String and capitalize the first letter of every word.