# Way of changing a string to first letter uppercase and the rest lower case in jsp

Tags: jsp

I need a quick compact way of changing a string to first letter uppercase and the rest lower case in jsp such as INDIAN --> Indian Like this format in jsp

String fullname = rs.getString("fullname").Lower();

The above function is not running

Comment: `The above is not running` ... you never even showed us any code.

Comment: String fullname = rs.getString("fullname").Lower();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capitalize the first letter of a String in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904579/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Use `str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);`