# How to create only capital letters in the beginning of words?

Tags: java

I need to make a method that makes capital letters only at the beginning of words, is something easy maybe but I haven't been able to make it work so far. Cause the use case I have tested it are diff,  Cause I don't have only the case where the first character is a string it can be a number or something else.

```
The result I want :
test => Test
test start now => Test start now.
2test start now => 2test start now
_test => _test
-test => -test
```

Comment: user `str.toUpperCase()`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904579/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-java

Comment: Please provide the code you attempted to write and discuss how it's not working.

Comment: as mentioned, you can use toUpperCase().
forexample, substring the first letter and substring the rest of the word. Make the first letter capital then concatenate the whole thing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capitalize the first letter of a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904579/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check if the first char is Alphabetic
2. Change the letter to upper case

```
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList("test => Test",
            "test start now => Test start now.",
            "2test start now => 2test start now",
            "_test => _test",
            "-test => -test");

    @Test
    public void firstLetterUpperCase() {
        // Iterate the values
        values.stream()
                // Check if the first char is Alphabetic
                .filter(text -> Character.isAlphabetic(text.charAt(0)))
                // Capital first letter and print
                .forEach(text -> System.out.println(text.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + text.substring(1)));
    }
```

Output

```
Test => Test
Test start now => Test start now.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "text";
String capitalize = text.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + text.substring(1);
```

It takes first character, and does `toUpperCase()`, then add the rest of the string.

If first character is not a letter, `toUpperCase()` won't change it.

- `"-".toUpperCase()` is `"-"`
- `"1".toUpperCase()` is `"1"`
- `"a".toUpperCase()` is `"A"`
- `"A".toUpperCase()` is `"A"`

Comment: code dump with no explanation is unhelpful. add an explanation how come this works for cases that do not start with letter

Comment: It takes first character, and does toUpperCase(), then add the rest of the string.
If first character is not a letter, toUpperCase() won't change it.
"-".toUpperCase() is "-"
"1".toUpperCase() is "1"
"a".toUpperCase() is "A"
"A".toUpperCase() is "A"

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `org.apache.commons.text.WordUtils.capitalize​(String str, char... delimiters)` [Javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/WordUtils.html#capitalize(java.lang.String,char...)) from `apache.commons-text` to captalize words.

Against your request, it capitalizes all words in a string/sentence not only the first character.

To uppercase the first character of a `String` use `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
.capitalize(String str)` ([Javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#capitalize-java.lang.String-)) from the `apache.commons-lang` package.