# How do I build this words to one sentence after looping?

Tags: java, string, loops

Am Looping through a sentence splitting it to capitalize.But its hard to build it back after getting the individual words.

```
String str = "Not the answer you're looking for.";
     StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 String oneWord =" ";
    for (String word : str.toLowerCase().split(" ")){
        char firstLetter = word.substring(0,1).toUpperCase().charAt(0);
       oneWord  = firstLetter + word.substring(1);

        System.out.println(stringBuilder.append(oneWord + " "));

    }

}
```

I expect to get only one fully built String "Not The Answer You're Looking For."

Comment: Please provide the incorrect result you are getting instead

Comment: Hope this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904579/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-java

Comment: `char firstLetter = word.substring(0,1).toUpperCase().charAt(0);` would IMHO be more readable as  `char firstLetter = Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0));`

Answer (score 2):

```
  String str = "Not the answer you're looking for.";
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  String oneWord =" ";
  for (String word : str.toLowerCase().split(" ")){
    char firstLetter = word.substring(0,1).toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    oneWord  = firstLetter + word.substring(1);
    stringBuilder.append(oneWord + " ");
  }
  System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
```

You are not getting just one string because you use `System.out.println` inside `for` loop.

Consider my example above

Answer (score 1):

```
oneWord += firstLetter + word.substring(1) + " ";
```

after loop

```
oneWord = oneWord.trim();
System.out.println(oneWord);
```

So the solution is:

```
  String str = "Not the answer you're looking for.";
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (String word : str.toLowerCase().split(" ")) {
    sb.append(str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()); 
    sb.append(str.substring(1));
    sb.append(" ");
  }
  System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString().trim());
```

Also your solution is not optimal.
Check String.join() or use somth like this

```
Arrays.stream(str.toLowerCase().split(" "))
   .map(word -> str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1))
   .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```