# Translate days name using ENUM in java

Tags: java, enums

I'm new in ENUMS. I'm looking for possibility to translate English names of days to Polish using ENUM class. What actually would I like to do?
In my program I'm using `LocalDate` library and `getDayOfWeek()` method. My goal is made something like this: `String day = Days(someDate.getDayOfWeek().toString())` and if `someDate.getDayOfWeek()` is MONDAY, the method give me translated day "Poniedziałek".

```
public enum Days {
     MONDAY {
        public String toString() {
            return "Poniedziałek";
        }
    },
// other days ...
}
```

It is possible with enums? Or there is something better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is possible with enums?

Of course, but not necessary.

> Or there is something better solution?

Yes, use the built in functionality. Java already supports representation of dates in human readable form. Use the below code:

```
DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.forLanguageTag("pl-PL"));
```

It returns:

> poniedziałek

Comment: This is the best approach! But how about capitalized names?

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you.

Comment: @marcin.programuje I am not sure why the polish locale does not have a capitalized first letter. Using english, you'd get "Monday". You can use the solution here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904579/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-java