# force to write first word as uppercase in searchview in android

Tags: java, android

I have this code but it is all cap is there any solution ?
I need first word as cap and the rest as lower

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.about_us_menu,menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search here...");

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            processsearch(s);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            processsearch(s);
            return false;
        }
    });
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: example added check it please

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904579/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-java):

```
String name = "mohsen Naderzadeh";
String s1 = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
String nameCapitalized = s1 + name.substring(1);
System.out.println(nameCapitalized);
```

Answer (score 0):

the following method will check the string and if its length is greater then 0 and the first character is an alphabetic then it will capitalize it:

```
String search = "sometext to search";
if(search.length() > 0 && Character.isAlphabetic(search.charAt(0))) {
    search = String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(search.charAt(0))) 
            + (search.length() > 1 ? search.substring(1) : "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below input type.

```
searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `onQueryTextChange` use this:

```
    if(s.length()==1){
         s=s.toUpperCase();
         //set s as search text
    }
```