# Is there an equivalent of ucwords in java

Tags: java, php, android

In php, the method `ucwords` converts any string in a string where each words first character is in uppercase, and all other characters are lower case.

I always end up making my own implementation, and I'm wondering if a standard method exists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149855/how-to-upper-case-every-first-letter-of-word-in-a-string

Comment: @Jarrod -- the link's broken. The Apache StringUtils follows WordUtils algo. As mentioned in JavaDoc

Comment: @Nishant: the link works for me...

Comment: @posdef ooh. Did not for me. In fact, I have just updated with the correct link in that answer.  BTW, I was talking about the WordUtil's link given in the answer, not the link to the answer.

Comment: The php call `ucwords` is short hand for `upper case words`.  The process of converting a lower case word to an upper case word is typically called `capitalization`.

Comment: Please note that capitalization could be complicated for some Unicode characters. There are upper-case, lower-case and title-case in some languages. Please refer to ICU page http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/casemappings for details

Comment: @Tommy Siu  StringUtils uses [TitleCase](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#TITLECASE_LETTER) to circumvent the Unicode char issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's called **capitalization**. Use Apache Commons's StringUtils to do [that](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).

See more here:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

WordUtils is also worth looking at. See [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html)

Comment: Ok thanks for the link. I won't be able to use it much though, as I'm working on Android (which does not include the apache org.apache.commons.lang library).

Comment: @XGouchet That's weird. You **can** use external Jar in Android project. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project

Comment: @XGouchet please tag your question as android

Comment: Yes, I know I can but I want to keep my apps small as possible and integrating a jar just for this small feature is not a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

Otherwise it's a rather simple fix such as; `String string1 = someString.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + someString.substring(1);`

You can put it in a function, and call it whenever you need. Saves you the trouble of maintaining libraries you don't need. (not that apache commons is ever trouble, but you get the point..)

EDIT: `someString.substring(1)` part can be written as `someString.substring(1).toLowerCase()` just to make sure that the rest of the string is in lowercase

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about any direct equivalent, but you can always write one:

```
public static String capitalize(String input) {
   if (input == null || input.length() <= 0) {
     return input;
   }
   char[] chars = new char[1];
   input.getChars(0, 1, chars, 0);
   if (Character.isUpperCase(chars[0])) {
     return input;
   } else {
     StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(input.length());
     buffer.append(Character.toUpperCase(chars[0]));
     buffer.append(input.toCharArray(), 1, input.length()-1);
     return buffer.toString();
   }
}
```