# How to capitalize the first letter of word in a string using Java?

Tags: java

Example strings

```
one thousand only
two hundred
twenty
seven
```

How do I change the first character of a string in capital letter and not change the case of any of the other letters?

After the change it should be:

```
One thousand only
Two hundred
Twenty
Seven
```

Note: I don't want to use the apache.commons.lang.WordUtils to do this.

Comment: @eat_a_lemon: much better to use Character.toUpperCase(), as it deals with cases other than a-z (e.g. numbers, punctuation, letters with diacritics, non-Latin characters).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149855/

Answer (score 559, accepted):

If you only want to capitalize the first letter of a string named `input` and leave the rest alone:

```
String output = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
```

Now `output` will have what you want. Check that your `input` is at least one character long before using this, otherwise you'll get an exception.

Comment: Also, I would first take the entire input and make it lower-case or rework your example as follows: String output = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1).toLowerCase();

Comment: And you want to check the length of the string, as it could be 1 letter string, or even 0.

Comment: I found this here for getter and setter name creation, therefore to LowerCase on the rest of the String will break the field naming. Given answer is perfect for me.

Answer (score 90):

```
public String capitalizeFirstLetter(String original) {
    if (original == null || original.length() == 0) {
        return original;
    }
    return original.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + original.substring(1);
}
```

Just... a complete solution, I see it kind of just ended up combining what everyone else ended up posting =P.

Comment: Nice. I "one-linered" it:

`return original.length() == 0 ? original : original.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + original.substring(1);`

Comment: @mharper: `if length() == 0`, can't we safely say that it's `""` and return that instead of `original`? Saves us a few characters in a one-liner. I ask because I feel like Java is a language so full of gotcha's, I honestly wouldn't be surprised if there was some other way to have a string of length zero.

Comment: You speak all truth @ArtOfWarfare.

Comment: Note: you may also want to make this working with non-english letters. In that case you should specify locale in toUpperCase() method.

Comment: It's not possible to use `String.toUpperCase(Locale)` for an arbitrary string, because the Locale has to match the text. Yes, it should be used, but it's not always clear which `Locale` to use...

Answer (score 87):

Simplest way is to use `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` class

`StringUtils.capitalize(Str);`

Comment: Little side-note here. It works only for strings that are not already capitalized.

Comment: @jobbert Please clarify your comment. If the strings are already capitalized, will it uncapitalized those despite being a method named `capitalize`?

Comment: [According to the docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#capitalize-java.lang.String-) only the first character is changed, so this is only helpful if you can predict your input well enough to know there are no other chars that may be uppercase.

Answer (score 28):

Also, There is `org.springframework.util.StringUtils` in **Spring Framework**:

```
StringUtils.capitalize(str);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
String sentence = "ToDAY   WeAthEr   GREat";    
public static String upperCaseWords(String sentence) {
        String words[] = sentence.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim().split(" ");
        String newSentence = "";
        for (String word : words) {
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
                newSentence = newSentence + ((i == 0) ? word.substring(i, i + 1).toUpperCase(): 
                    (i != word.length() - 1) ? word.substring(i, i + 1).toLowerCase() : word.substring(i, i + 1).toLowerCase().toLowerCase() + " ");
        }

        return newSentence;
    }
//Today Weather Great
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of OP. Since it changes the case of the other letters.

Comment: Look at the question. Probably, you did not get the question well.

Answer (score 7):

[`StringUtils.capitalize(str)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#capitalize-java.lang.String-)

from [apache commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).

Comment: Duplicate of [Haseeb answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36474999/1033581).

Answer (score 3):

Here you go (hope this give you the idea):

```
/*************************************************************************
 *  Compilation:  javac Capitalize.java
 *  Execution:    java Capitalize < input.txt
 * 
 *  Read in a sequence of words from standard input and capitalize each
 *  one (make first letter uppercase; make rest lowercase).
 *
 *  % java Capitalize
 *  now is the time for all good 
 *  Now Is The Time For All Good 
 *  to be or not to be that is the question
 *  To Be Or Not To Be That Is The Question 
 *
 *  Remark: replace sequence of whitespace with a single space.
 *
 *************************************************************************/

public class Capitalize {

    public static String capitalize(String s) {
        if (s.length() == 0) return s;
        return s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            String line = StdIn.readLine();
            String[] words = line.split("\\s");
            for (String s : words) {
                StdOut.print(capitalize(s) + " ");
            }
            StdOut.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: and not change the case of the other letters. Also your use of `StdIn` and `StdOut` is not very Java-y. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
String s=t.getText().trim();
int l=s.length();
char c=Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0));
s=c+s.substring(1);
for(int i=1; i<l; i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i)==' ')
        {
            c=Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i+1));
            s=s.substring(0, i) + c + s.substring(i+2);
        }
    }
    t.setText(s);
```

Comment: This will uppercase the first letter of *each* word, not of the string as a whole. See the examples provided by OP. Also there could be problems if there is a space at the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you will get the best performance if you avoid `+` operator and use `concat()` in this case. It is the best option for merging just 2 strings (not so good for many strings though). In that case the code would look like this:

```
String output = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase().concat(input.substring(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Its simple only one line code is needed for this.
if `String A = scanner.nextLine();`
then you need to write this to display the string with this first letter capitalized.

`System.out.println(A.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + A.substring(1));`

And its done now.

Answer (score 1):

Example using StringTokenizer class :

```
String st = "  hello all students";
String st1;
char f;
String fs="";
StringTokenizer a= new StringTokenizer(st);
while(a.hasMoreTokens()){   
        st1=a.nextToken();
        f=Character.toUpperCase(st1.charAt(0));
        fs+=f+ st1.substring(1);
        System.out.println(fs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with StringBuilder:

```
value = new StringBuilder()
                .append(value.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase())
                .append(value.substring(1))
                .toString();
```

*.. based on previous answers*

Answer (score 1):

Adding everything together, it is a good idea to trim for extra white space at beginning of string.  Otherwise, .substring(0,1).toUpperCase will try to capitalize a white space.

```
    public String capitalizeFirstLetter(String original) {
        if (original == null || original.length() == 0) {
            return original;
        }
        return original.trim().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + original.substring(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My functional approach. its capstilise first character in sentence after whitescape in whole paragraph.

For capatilising only first character of the word just remove **.split(" ")**

```
           b.name.split(" ")
                 .filter { !it.isEmpty() }
                 .map { it.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() 
                 +it.substring(1).toLowerCase() }
                  .joinToString(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String capitalize(String str){
        String[] inputWords = str.split(" ");
        String outputWords = "";
        for (String word : inputWords){
            if (!word.isEmpty()){
                outputWords = outputWords + " "+StringUtils.capitalize(word);
            }
        }
        return outputWords;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update July 2019**

Currently, the most up-to-date library function for doing this is contained in 
`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

StringUtils.capitalize(myString);
```

If you're using Maven, import the dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you the same consistent output regardless of the value of your inputString:

```
if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(inputString)) {
    inputString = StringUtils.capitalize(inputString.toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Using String's `substring()` Method

```java
public static String capitalize(String str) {
    if(str== null || str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }

    return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
}
```

Now just call the `capitalize()` method to convert the first letter of a string to uppercase:

```java
System.out.println(capitalize("stackoverflow")); // Stackoverflow
System.out.println(capitalize("heLLo")); // HeLLo
System.out.println(capitalize(null)); // null
```

#### 2. Apache Commons Lang

The `StringUtils` class from Commons Lang provides the `capitalize()` method that can also be used for this purpose:

```java
System.out.println(StringUtils.capitalize("apache commons")); // Apache commons
System.out.println(StringUtils.capitalize("heLLO")); // HeLLO
System.out.println(StringUtils.uncapitalize(null)); // null
```

Add the following dependency to your `pom.xml` file (for Maven only):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is [an article](https://attacomsian.com/blog/capitalize-first-letter-of-string-java) that explains these two approaches in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Even for "simple" code, I would use libraries. The thing is not the code per se, but the already existing test cases covering exceptional cases. This could be `null`, empty strings, strings in other languages.

The word manipulation part has been moved out ouf Apache Commons Lang. It is now placed in [Apache Commons Text](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/). Get it via https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text.

You can use [WordUtils.capitalize(String str)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/index.html) from Apache Commons Text. It is more powerful than you asked for. It can also capitalize fulle (e.g., fixing `"oNe tousand only"`).

Since it works on complete text, one has to tell it to capitalize only the first word.

```java
WordUtils.capitalize("one thousand only", new char[0]);
```

Full JUnit class to enable playing with the functionality:

```java
package io.github.koppor;

import org.apache.commons.text.WordUtils;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class AppTest {

  @Test
  void test() {
    assertEquals("One thousand only", WordUtils.capitalize("one thousand only", new char[0]));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
char[] chars = {Character.toUpperCase(A.charAt(0)), 
Character.toUpperCase(B.charAt(0))};
String a1 = chars[0] + A.substring(1);
String b1 = chars[1] + B.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the `input` string:

```
Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(0)) + input.substring(1).toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
public string capitalize(str) {
    String[] array = str.split(" ");
    String newStr;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        newStr += array[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + array[i].substring(1) + " ";
    }
    return newStr.trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a NULL check and IndexOutOfBoundsException on the accepted answer.

```
String output = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
```

**Java Code:**

```
  class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Capitalize first letter ");
        System.out.println("Normal  check #1      : ["+ captializeFirstLetter("one thousand only")+"]");
        System.out.println("Normal  check #2      : ["+ captializeFirstLetter("two hundred")+"]");
        System.out.println("Normal  check #3      : ["+ captializeFirstLetter("twenty")+"]");
        System.out.println("Normal  check #4      : ["+ captializeFirstLetter("seven")+"]");

        System.out.println("Single letter check   : ["+captializeFirstLetter("a")+"]");
        System.out.println("IndexOutOfBound check : ["+ captializeFirstLetter("")+"]");
        System.out.println("Null Check            : ["+ captializeFirstLetter(null)+"]");
      }

      static String captializeFirstLetter(String input){
             if(input!=null && input.length() >0){
                input = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
            }
            return input;
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Normal  check #1      : [One thousand only]
Normal  check #2      : [Two hundred]
Normal  check #3      : [Twenty]
Normal  check #4      : [Seven]
Single letter check   : [A]
IndexOutOfBound check : []
Null Check            : [null]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String newString="";
        String test="Hii lets cheCk for BEING String";  
        String[] splitString = test.split(" ");
        for(int i=0; i<splitString.length; i++){
            newString= newString+ splitString[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() 
                    + splitString[i].substring(1,splitString[i].length()).toLowerCase()+" ";
        }
        System.out.println("the new String is "+newString);
    }
 }
```