# how to capitalize first letter of a dynamic button string

Tags: android, button

I have the following code in which I am trying to capitalize the first letter of the string. The code is as follows:

```
final Button headerButton =  (Button) View.inflate(EikonApplication.getAppContext(), R.layout.manage_markets_category_header_button, null);
headerButton.setOnClickListener(this);                      
headerButton.setText(header.getCategoryTitle().toLowerCase());
linearLayout.addView(headerButton);
```

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725892/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-word-in-a-string-using-java but Stack is complaining that marking it as such would make a circular duplicate list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
String title = header.getCategoryTitle().toSubString(0,1).toUperCase);
title += header.getCategoryTitle().toSubString(1).toLowerCase);

headerButton.setText(title);
```

Comment: Sorry, it should be subString();

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725892/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-word-in-a-string-using-java) is a great answer. Note that this is actually a `java` question, not merely `android`.

Answer (score 0):

Set android:inputType="textCapSentences" on your EditText.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Comment: I am not using edittext, just the code above. I tried    headerButton.setText(header.getCategoryTitle().toUpperCase().charAt(0)); didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
WordUtils.capitalize("i am fine") = "I Am Fine"
```

Not sure android support wordutils or not , if it support then its easy to use .

Answer (score 0):

```
public String capitalizeFirstLetterAndLowerCaseTheRest(String original) {
        if (original == null || original.length() == 0) {
            return original;
        }
        return original.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + original.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
```

Loop on it if you want to do it on every word.

Source : [How to capitalize the first letter of word in a string using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725892/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-word-in-a-string-using-java)