# Checking if the first character of a string is lower case

Tags: java

I am trying figure out how to change the character at position 0 of a string to uppercase if it is lower case. I am sorry if this is a dumb question, but it is stumping me. Something like this:

```
String myString = "hello";
if( //string position 0 is lowercase )
{
    char myChar = myString.charAt(0);
    myChar.toUpperCase();
}
```

I think .toUpperCase() only works for strings though. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This question is duplicated with 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/5725892/3057249

Comment: Are you wanting to change the `String` value?

Comment: Dang didn't realize it @BrunoCarneiro, Thank you it helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Character.isUpperCase()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/character_isuppercase.htm) to check if a character is upper case.

You can use [`Character.toUpperCase()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/character_touppercase.htm) to convert a single character to upper case.

Answer (score 0):

Think of changing `myString` to a char array and working it from that. The `Character` package in Java has some helpful functions:

```
String myString = "hello";
char[] sArr = myString.toCharArray();

sArr[0] = Character.toUpperCase(sArr[0]);

myString = new String(sArr);
```

EDIT: 
As pointed out by Scary Wombat, there is no need to check if the first char is upper or not. Simply call the `Character.toUpperCase(sArr[0])`. Whether it is upper or not doesn't effect the outcome.

Comment: why bother testing if the char is lowercase?

Comment: He specified in the question: I am trying figure out how to change the character at position 0 of a string to uppercase if it is lower case.

Comment: yes, but you could have cleaner code by simply calling `sArr[0] = Character.toUpperCase(sArr[0]);`

Comment: Actually you are absolutely right