# Text formatting (first letter uppercase, rest lowercase) in Apache FreeMarker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, formatting, freemarker

How do I format text in **Apache FreeMarker**?

I would like to add a new formatter that would format the value (taken from json). For example, the text `ANIMAL`would be formatted to `Animal`(ideally it would also work if the word `animal`was lowercase and it would format it to `Animal`).

I checked the available built-in functions for strings, but I can't find this particular one. https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capitalize the first letter of word in a string using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725892/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-word-in-a-string-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method that formats the word you want. In the example my method `format` enters a String which no matter how it is structured, it returns it with the first one in uppercase and the others in lowercase. You can see that I enter the word "ANIMAL" and it would return "Animal". It doesn't matter if the word is "aNiMaL", it always returns the same.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "ANIMAL";
        System.out.println(format(str)); // result: Animal
    }
    
    public static String format(String input) {
        return input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

For use in FreeMarker:
Modify the getters in the attributes where you want to format the String.

```java
public class entity {
    private String a;
    public String getA() {
        return format(this.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain further what your code does

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was very flat. Is that better?

Comment: Way better , Manuel .

Comment: Freemarker calls the getters of the selected attributes in the template. Just modify the getters. I made the edit to explain it. @JasperdeVries

Answer (score 1):

You could combine [`?lower_case`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_lower_case) and [`?cap_first`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_cap_first):

```
${"ANIMAL"?lower_case?cap_first}
```

Results in:

```
Animal
```