# android:capitalize not working

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a TextView.  I'm trying to capitalize the first letter in every word.

Here's the TextView:

```
 <TextView 
            android:text="TextView" 
            android:id="@+id/textView1" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
            android:textSize="30dip" 
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:capitalize="words">
        </TextView>
```

Here's how I'm adding the text:

```
TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    titleView.setText( section.replace("_", " ") );
```

Can I not add text dynamically and expect it to capitalize the words?  Is another trait interfering with `android:capitalize`?  Is `android:capitalize` broken?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`capitalize` is basically just a `KeyListener` that you can set in XML, so it only applies to text input by the user. [As the documentation states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:capitalize) (emphasis mine):

> If set, specifies that this TextView has a textual input method and should automatically capitalize **what the user types**.

There is a related question on [how to capitalize the first letter of every word in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149855/how-to-upper-case-every-first-letter-of-word-in-a-string) which has some helpful answers.

Answer (score 16):

If you're targeting API Level 14 and above, you should use

> android:textAllCaps="true"

Otherwise, you'll have to implement this behavior yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Now I know why I can't get this to work on API Level 8. :)

Answer (score 8):

`android:capitalize` is now deprecated.

Instead of using `android:capitalize="words"`, you should consider using `android:inputType="textCapWords"`.

Depending on your needs, you can also use multiple values, such as `android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer but I think might help someone...

If you are comfortable with capitilizing the dynamic text in the java code then you can use:

```
textView.setText(text.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

@Shine's answer is correct I don't know why it was down voted. android:capitalize was deprecated in API 3. Unfortunately the TextView docs fail to indicate this, the proof is burried in R.attr:

[R.attr](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#capitalize)

Android studio also fails to inform you that this attribute is deprecated. Another 30 mins I'll never get back, thanks google!

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin gives

```
  private val replacementTransformationMethod: ReplacementTransformationMethod =
    object : ReplacementTransformationMethod() {
        override fun getOriginal(): CharArray {
            return charArrayOf(
                'a',
                'b',
                'c',
                'd',
                'e',
                'f',
                'g',
                'h',
                'i',
                'j',
                'k',
                'l',
                'm',
                'n',
                'o',
                'p',
                'q',
                'r',
                's',
                't',
                'u',
                'v',
                'w',
                'x',
                'y',
                'z'
            )
        }

        override fun getReplacement(): CharArray {
            return charArrayOf(
                'A',
                'B',
                'C',
                'D',
                'E',
                'F',
                'G',
                'H',
                'I',
                'J',
                'K',
                'L',
                'M',
                'N',
                'O',
                'P',
                'Q',
                'R',
                'S',
                'T',
                'U',
                'V',
                'W',
                'X',
                'Y',
                'Z'
            )
        }
    }
```

then in  the block   `override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`

set

```
this.textUserCode.transformationMethod = replacementTransformationMethod
```

Answer (score -1):

android:capitalize is deprecated on ICS, so I guess it should be better to do it in code (i.e. with  *String.toUpperCase()*)

Another try could be

```
 android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

but I guess it would require an EditText to work.

I don't know if this is the reason for your code, **what version are you targeting**?