# Android - Editing my String so each word starts with a capital

Tags: java, android, text, text-formatting

I was wondering if someone could provide me some code or point me towards a tutrial which explain how I can convert my string so that each word begins with a capital.

I would also like to convert a different string in italics.

Basically, what my app is doing is getting data from several EditText boxes and then on a button click is being pushed onto the next page via intent and being concatenated into 1 paragraph. Therefore, I assume I need to edit my string on the intial page and make sure it is passed through in the same format.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149855/how-to-upper-case-every-first-letter-of-word-in-a-string) as it is similar to yours

Comment: The 'convert to italics' part is a totally different thing. One thing is a string (a sequence of chars abstracted from any format) and other is formatted-text. Probably you want to modify font properties of some UI widgets to show its text in italics.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html). The [capitalize](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29) method will do the work.

For eg:

```
WordUtils.capitalize("i am FINE") = "I Am FINE"
```

or

```
WordUtils.capitalizeFully("i am FINE") = "I Am Fine"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function

```
public static String capEachWord(String source){
        String result = "";
        String[] splitString = source.split(" ");
        for(String target : splitString){
            result
                    += Character.toUpperCase(target.charAt(0))
                    + target.substring(1) + " ";
        }
        return result.trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using simple Java built-in functions.

Try something like the following (method names may not be exactly right, doing it off the top of my head):

```
String label = Capitalize("this is my test string");    


public String Capitalize(String testString)
{
    String[] brokenString = testString.split(" ");
    String newString = "";

    for(String s : brokenString)
    {
        s.charAt(0) = s.charAt(0).toUpper();
        newString += s + " ";
    }

    return newString;
}
```

Give this a try, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 
*`android:inputType="textCapWords"`* to your EditText in layout xml. 
This wll make all the words start with the Caps letter.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in Java, and String.charAt returns a value, not a reference that you can set (like in C++).  Pheonixblade9's will not compile.  This does what Pheonixblade9 suggests, except it compiles.

```
public String capitalize(String testString) {
    String[] brokenString = testString.split(" ");
    String newString = "";

    for (String s : brokenString) {
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        chars[0] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[0]);
        newString = newString + new String(chars) + " ";
    }

    //the trim removes trailing whitespace
    return newString.trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String source = "hello good old world";
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

String[] strArr = source.split(" ");
for (String str : strArr) {
    char[] stringArray = str.trim().toCharArray();
    stringArray[0] = Character.toUpperCase(stringArray[0]);
    str = new String(stringArray);

    res.append(str).append(" ");
}

System.out.print("Result: " + res.toString().trim());
```